# Summation of logs

Tags: number-theory, logarithms, summation

Are there any useful identities for quickly calculating the sum of consecutive logs? For example $\sum_{k=1}^{N} log(k)$ or something to this effect. I should add that I am writing code to do this (as opposed to doing this on a calculator) so N can be very large.

Comment: $\log a+\log b=\log (a\cdot b)$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For large $N$, we have $N!\approx N^Ne^{-N}\sqrt {2\pi N}$ (Stirling formula) and hence
$$\sum_{k=1}^N\ln k\approx\left( N+\frac12\right)\ln N-N+\frac12\ln(2\pi).$$

Comment: What expression would you get for $\sum_{k=1}^N \log^2 k$?

Comment: It’s interesting to note that $\frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi)$ is the divergent sum of the logarithms of all natural numbers

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:**

Use the fact that $\log(a)+\log(b)=\log(ab)$

Your expression simply becomes $\sum_1^N \log k=\log(N!)$, and now you can have [Stirling Approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) to approximate $N!$

Comment: I am trying to do this with a computer, so for large $N$, calculating N! may not be possible

Comment: @Inceptio, it's better to show the means than end

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: Considered it. Edited.:)

Comment: Will the approximation of N! interfere with the log calculation? I am not sure what O(ln(n)) is

Comment: @user74255: No. You can calculate the approximate value of it, and then take $\log$ of it.

Comment: Perhaps instead of calculating $N!$ and then taking the $log$, you could in one step calculate the log-gamma function, i.e., $ln Γ (N+1)$.  You didn't mention what language you are coding in; this would be very easy in, say, Mathematica.

Comment: @Ray I am using Python

Comment: @Inceptio, what you suggest is a very numerically unstable approach

Comment: @Ray: Stirling Approximation can reduce the load.

Comment: I'm not talking about computational complexity--you can read about numerical stability here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_stability

Answer (score 7):

The [Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula), can also be used to get an asymptotic expansion. It gives
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\log(k)=\overbrace{\vphantom{\frac12}C}^{\frac12\log(2\pi)}+\overbrace{\vphantom{\frac12}n\log(n)-n}^{\int f(n)\,\mathrm{d}n}+\overbrace{\frac12\log(n)}^{\frac12f(n)}+\overbrace{\frac1{12n}}^{\frac1{12}f'(n)}-\overbrace{\frac1{360n^3}}^{\frac1{720}f'''(n)}+\dots
$$
The constant $\frac12\log(2\pi)$ is derived as in the [proof of Stirling's Formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95454).

Answer (score 3):

In the particular case of
$$
\sum_{k=1}^N\log k=\log N!=\log\Gamma(N+1)
$$
this is just the loggama function, which is implemented in many software systems. This is fast and accurate.

For example, it is `lngamma` in GP, `lgamma` in C (math.h), `LogGamma` in Mathematica, `lnGAMMA` in Maple, `LogGamma` in Magma, `gammaln` in MatLab, `lnGamma` in Mathcad, `log_gamma` in Sage, `math.lgamma` in Python, and `gammaln` in Perl (Math::SpecFun::Gamma).