# Asymptotic development of a sum

Tags: real-analysis, summation, asymptotics

I'd like to find an asymptotic development for
$\sum_{k=2}^{n} \ln(k)$

I know this sum is equivalent to $n\ln(n)-n$ but I cannot find more terms.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Look into the [Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula), but do look at the links mentioned in José's comment.

Comment: Using Mathematica: $\frac{1}{1188 n^9}-\frac{1}{1680 n^7}+\frac{1}{1260 n^5}-\frac{1}{360 n^3}-n+\frac{1}{12 n}+\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \ln (n)+\frac{1}{2} \ln (2 \pi )$

Comment: Probably, the shortcut is to use the Stirling's approximation $\displaystyle n!=\sqrt{2\pi n}\Big(\frac{n}{e}\Big)^n\Big(1+\frac{1}{12n}+...\Big)$ and notice that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=2}^n\ln k=\sum_{k=1}^n\ln k=\ln (n!)$

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [Summation of logs](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/385574)

Comment: Is it possible to do so by using the following inequality: ln (k)<= $ \int_{k}^(k+1) (ln(x)dx) $ <= ln(k+1)