# Bounds for $\binom{n}{cn}$ with $0 < c < 1$.

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Are there really good upper and lower bounds for $\binom{n}{cn}$ when $c$ is a constant $0 < c < 1$?  I know that $\left(\frac{1}{c^{cn}}\right) \leq \binom{n}{cn}  \leq \left(\frac{e}{c}\right)^{cn}$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using Stirling's formula, 
$$ \begin{align}{n\choose cn}&\approx\frac{n^n e^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi n}}{(cn)^{cn}e^{-cn}\sqrt{2\pi cn}\cdot ((1-c)n)^{(1-c)n}e^{-(1-c)n}\sqrt{2\pi (1-c)n}}\\&=\frac{1}{c^{cn}(1-c)^{(1-c)n}\sqrt{2\pi c(1-c)n}}\end{align}.$$
You can turn $\approx$ to good upper and lower bounds by fillig in the details of the error term in the Stirling formula.

**Edit:** For every $n\geqslant1$ and every $c$ in $(0,1)$ such that $cn$ is an integer,
$$
\frac{2\pi/\mathrm e^2}{c^{cn}(1-c)^{(1-c)n}\sqrt{2\pi c(1-c)n}}\leqslant{n\choose cn}\leqslant\frac{\mathrm e/\sqrt{2\pi}}{c^{cn}(1-c)^{(1-c)n}\sqrt{2\pi c(1-c)n}}.
$$
The ratio between the upper and lower bounds is $\lt1.275$.

Comment: The page @Hagen linked to explains that the ratio between any factorial and its Stirling equivalent is always between $1$ and $a=\mathrm e/\sqrt{2\pi}\lt1.09$. Since binomial coefficients are ratios of one factorial by two other factorials, multiplying the equivalent by $1/a^2$ and $a$ yields rigorous lower and upper bounds. Better estimates are also on [the same WP page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Speed_of_convergence_and_error_estimates) (did you read it?).

Comment: The link is in your comment. I did not suggest to use convergent series, only the rigorous bounds, valid for every $n$, which are on the WP page.

Comment: @Hagen I took the liberty to edit your answer, adding an expansion of the hint you give at the end, since this seems to be what the OP is after. Of course, if you object, please revert to the previous version (and accept my apologies).

Comment: @Anush You are welcome. Whether the absolute bounds in the Edit or the moving bounds based on the $\exp(1+1/(12n))$ factor explained on the WP page are best, really depends on the setting.

Comment: @Did: I don't any link in Hagen's answer. I assume you refer to the link in your comment.

Comment: @robjohn This phrase is answering a now deleted comment, where the link appeared. As a mod, do you see deleted comments?

Answer (score 3):

Stirling's Asymptotic Expansion, [derived here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95454/13854), is
$$
n!=\sqrt{2\pi n}\,n^ne^{-n}\left(1+\frac1{12n}+\frac1{288n^2}-\frac{139}{51840n^3}-\frac{571}{2488320n^4}+O\left(\frac1{n^5}\right)\right)
$$
From which we get
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{n!}{(cn)!((1-c)n)!}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{\left(c^c(1-c)^{1-c}\right)^{-n}}{\sqrt{2\pi c(1-c)n}}\small\left(1-\frac{1-c+c^2}{12c(1-c)}\frac1n+\frac{1-2c+3c^2-2c^3+c^4}{288c^2(1-c)^2}\frac1{n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)\right)
\end{align}
$$

---

**Absolute Bounds**

For $n\ge1$,
$$
\sqrt{2\pi n}\,n^ne^{-n}\left(1+\frac1{12n}\right)\le n!\le\sqrt{2\pi n}\,n^ne^{-n}\left(1+\frac1{12n}+\frac1{288n^2}\right)
$$
which gives
$$
\sqrt{2\pi n}\,n^ne^{-n}\le n!\le\frac{313}{288}\sqrt{2\pi n}\,n^ne^{-n}
$$
From which we get, for $1\le cn\le n-1$,
$$
\left(\frac{288}{313}\right)^2\frac{\left(c^c(1-c)^{1-c}\right)^{-n}}{\sqrt{2\pi c(1-c)n}}
\le\binom{n}{cn}
\le\frac{313}{288}\frac{\left(c^c(1-c)^{1-c}\right)^{-n}}{\sqrt{2\pi c(1-c)n}}
$$
Note that
$$
\frac{e}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\doteq1.0844\lt1.0868\doteq\frac{313}{288}
$$
so this is close to Hagen von Eitzen's answer.

---

The bound mentioned in Hagen's answer is based on the fact that the ratio
$$
\frac{\Gamma(n)}{\sqrt{2\pi n}\,n^ne^{-n}}
$$
is decreasing in $n$. Thus, the greatest ratio is for $n=1$ and therefore,
$$
\sqrt{2\pi n}\,n^ne^{-n}\le n!\le\frac{e}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sqrt{2\pi n}\,n^ne^{-n}
$$

Comment: This probably uses the postfactor $1+c/(12n)+\cdots$ instead of $1+1/(12cn)+\cdots$ for $(cn)!$ (and similarly for $((1-c)n)!$).

Comment: @Did: Ack, yes. Fixing..

Comment: I love the upvotes... By the way, using asymptotic expansions seems offtopic if the OP is interested in nonasymptotic bounds.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the error. However, as for the asymptotic expansion being off-topic, I did not notice that the OP was not interested in asymptotic bounds. I was simply supplying what "error terms" I could.

Comment: "How can I use that to give strict upper or lower bounds?"

Comment: That looked to be in response to a pretty obscure answer, since $H(c)$ is not defined. I appreciate your comments as to how others feel about my answer.

Comment: @robjohn, Entropy function has pretty standard definition, isn't it?

Comment: Anyway I added the definition.

Comment: @ArashBeh: Do you mean [this entropy function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_entropy_function)? If so, then
$$
\begin{align}
e^{nH(c)}
&=e^{-nc\log_2(c)-n(1-c)\log_2(1-c)}\\
&=\left(c^c(1-c)^{1-c}\right)^{-n/\log(2)}
\end{align}
$$
which is wrong by a factor of $\log(2)$ in the exponent. Supposing that we use $\log_e$ instead of $\log_2$ in the definition of $H$, then there is a missing factor of $\sqrt{2\pi c(1-c)n}$. However, it is interesting that $e^{nH(c)\log(2)}$ is as close as it is for such a simple expression.

Comment: @ArashBeh sorry, I was in the process of writing the last comment when you posted your response. Ignore the part before using $\log_e$.

Comment: @robjohn, Such bounds can be obtained from an information theoretic perspective and can be sometimes very interesting.

Comment: "I appreciate your comments as to how others feel about my answer"... What do you mean? I do not understand.

Comment: @Did: "I love the upvotes..."

Comment: Yes, and? A new example that at least some users do not really look at the answers (but just check it is more or less written in mathematese, and, probably, have a look at the author's name). No big deal.

Comment: @Did: Hagen's answer did not even mention any bound; he only mentioned Stirling's Formula. I see that you added the actual bounds to that answer *after* my answer (and Hagen had 7 votes). I see no need to belittle my votes in this case.

Comment: No. Hagen explicitely mentioned and precisely described, **from the start**, how to get rigorous bounds using **the error term** in Stirling's formula, all I did was to write down his directions. Anyway, when I wrote the side remark about upvotes, your answer was *wrong* and got 2. That makes two reasons why I am surprised to see you nitpick at the remark. A third is that it obviously addressed the *general* phenomenon of un-informed upvotes on MSE. Believe it or not, I do not care about the upvotes this specific answer receives. (But I do resent being forced to explain such trivialities.)

Comment: @Did: He said "error term" which is not clear. There are several error terms for Stirling's approximation, one of which I incorporated (incorrectly but then corrected) in my answer. Once it was pointed out that the OP clarified what he wanted in a comment, I used my error term to get a bound $\frac14\%$ looser than yours. Don't get me wrong, I appreciate the notice that I had used $\frac cn$ instead of $\frac1{cn}$. However, I was suspicious of the formula soon after I posted (it seemed too nice), so I was checking it.

Comment: Wrong again, on several counts. (1) "Error term" is crystal clear. (2) The OP "clarified" much earlier than you posted. Yeah, deleted comments. // Enough said.

Comment: @Did: (1) Obviously you think so, but when there are more than one, I don't think so. (2) I didn't say that the OP did not clarify earlier than I posted. I mentioned earlier that I had not read that comment since it "[looked to be in response to a pretty obscure answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496707/bounds-for-binomncn-with-0-c-1/497412#comment1069129_497412)"

Answer (score 1):

Hint: as $n$ goes to infinity, you can approximate $\binom{n}{cn}$ by Entropy function as follows:
$$
\binom{n}{cn}\approx e^{nH(c)}.
$$
where $H(c)=-c\log(c)-(1-c)\log(1-c)$