# Upper bound for ${n \choose cn}$

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients

Is it true that for any $0<c<1/2$ and sufficiently large $n'$, there exists a $d <2$ such that ${n \choose cn} < d^n$ for all $n>n'$?  Clearly we have to assume $cn$ is an integer.

I saw [Bounds for $\binom{n}{cn}$ with $0 < c < 1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496707/bounds-for-binomncn-with-0-c-1/496713) but I couldn't see how to use that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the Stirling formula.

When you do so, it remains
$$
\binom n{cn}\sim
\frac{1}{\sqrt{c(1-c)n}c^{cn}(1-c)^{(1-c)n}}
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{c(1-c)n}}
\left(c^{-c}(1-c)^{c-1}\right)^n
$$
For $n$ large enough and $d>
(1-c)^{c-1}c^{-c}$, you have
$$
\binom n{cn}< d^n
$$

Now as $c<1/2$,

[image]

you can take $d$ such as 
$$
(1-c)^{c-1}c^{-c}<d<2
$$

---

A direct proof of the last inequality is also possible:
using the AM-GM inequality,

$$
(1-c)^{c-1}c^{-c}
=\left[\frac 1{1-c}\right]^{1-c}
\left[\frac 1{c}\right]^{c}<
\frac 1{1-c}{1-c} + \frac 1cc=2
$$
with a strict inequality because $c\neq \frac 12 \implies 1-c\neq c$