# Proof of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^nn!}{n^n\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{2\pi}$

Tags: limits

I'm looking for a proof of the following limit:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^nn!}{n^n\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{2\pi}$$
This follows from Stirling's Formula, but how can it be proven?

Comment: It's [Stirling's_approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Comment: @Jlamprong: Yes, but what is the proof?

Comment: See [here](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/02/254a-notes-0a-stirlings-formula/) or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94722/stirlings-formula-proof).

Comment: 1) log the expression 2) use Euler-Maclaurin formula

Comment: I think it is worth noting the link between [Euler's initial integral expression for the $\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#History), and the fact that $\displaystyle\int\ln x~dx=x\ln\dfrac xe$ , which, when exponentiated, becomes $\bigg(\dfrac xe\bigg)^x$

Comment: @Alex: that leaves the quantity we are trying to find as the constant of integration. We can compute the constant numerically that way, but I don't think we can show that it is exactly $\sqrt{2\pi}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Existence of the Limit**

The ratio of two consecutive terms is
$$
\left.\frac{e^nn!}{n^{n+1/2}}\middle/\frac{e^{n-1}(n-1)!}{(n-1)^{n-1/2}}\right.
=e\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n-1/2}\tag{1}
$$
Using the Taylor approximation
$$
\log\left(1-\frac1n\right)=-\frac1n-\frac1{2n^2}-\frac1{3n^3}+O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)\tag{2}
$$
we can compute the logarithm of the right hand side of $(1)$:
$$
1+\left(n-\frac12\right)\log\left(1-\frac1n\right)
=-\frac1{12n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)\tag{3}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^nn!}{n^{n+1/2}}
&=e\prod_{n=2}^\infty\left(\frac{e^nn!}{n^{n+1/2}}\middle/\frac{e^{n-1}(n-1)!}{(n-1)^{n-1/2}}\right)\\
&=e\prod_{n=2}^\infty\left(e\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n-1/2}\right)\\
&=\exp\left(1+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(1+\left(n-\frac12\right)\log\left(1-\frac1n\right)\right)\right)\\
&=\exp\left(1+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(-\frac1{12n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)\right)\right)\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Since the sum on the right hand side of $(4)$ converges, so does the limit on the left hand side.

---

**Log-Convexity of $\boldsymbol{\Gamma(x)}$**

Since $\Gamma(x)$ is log-convex,
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{n}\,\Gamma(n+1/2)
&\le\sqrt{n}\,\Gamma(n)^{1/2}\,\Gamma(n+1)^{1/2}\\
&=\Gamma(n+1)\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\Gamma(n+1)
&\le\Gamma(n+1/2)^{1/2}\,\Gamma(n+3/2)^{1/2}\\
&=\sqrt{n+1/2}\,\Gamma(n+1/2)\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1/2}}\le\sqrt{n}\frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{\Gamma(n+1)}\le1\tag{7}
$$
Thus, by the Squeeze Theorem,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}\frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{\Gamma(n+1)}=1\tag{8}
$$

---

**Using the Recursion for $\boldsymbol{\Gamma(x)}$**

Using the identity $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$,
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{n}\color{#C00000}{\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}}\color{#00A000}{\frac1{2^nn!}}
&=\sqrt{n}\frac{\color{#C00000}{1}}{\color{#00A000}{2}}\cdot\frac{\color{#C00000}{3}}{\color{#00A000}{4}}\cdot\frac{\color{#C00000}{5}}{\color{#00A000}{6}}\cdots\frac{\color{#C00000}{2n-1}}{\color{#00A000}{2n}}\\
&=\sqrt{n}\frac{\color{#C00000}{1/2}}{\color{#00A000}{1}}\cdot\frac{\color{#C00000}{3/2}}{\color{#00A000}{2}}\cdot\frac{\color{#C00000}{5/2}}{\color{#00A000}{3}}\cdots\frac{\color{#C00000}{n-1/2}}{\color{#00A000}{n}}\\
&=\sqrt{n}\color{#C00000}{\frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{\Gamma(1/2)}}\color{#00A000}{\frac{\Gamma(1)}{\Gamma(n+1)}}\tag{9}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Value of the Limit**

Combining $(8)$ and $(9)$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{e^nn!}{n^{n+1/2}}\right)^{-1}
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{2n}(2n)!}{(2n)^{2n+1/2}}\left(\frac{n^{n+1/2}}{e^nn!}\right)^2\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt2\,4^n}\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt2}\frac{\Gamma(1)}{\Gamma(1/2)}\sqrt{n}\frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{\Gamma(n+1)}\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\tag{10}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^nn!}{n^{n+1/2}}=\sqrt{2\pi}\tag{11}
$$

Comment: I've just noticed that some of this argument can be found in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/932509).

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

> With the
>   [Stirling's Approximation for $n!$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) $\ds{\approx \root{2\pi}n^{n + 1/2}\expo{-n}}$

\begin{align}
\color{#66f}{\large\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}{\expo{n}n! \over n^{n}\root{n}}}
=\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}
{\expo{n}\color{#c00000}{\root{2\pi}n^{n + 1/2}\expo{-n}} \over n^{n + 1/2}}
=\color{#66f}{\large\root{2\pi}} \approx {\tt 2.5066}
\end{align}