# Estimating the behavior for large $n$

Tags: asymptotics, power-series, exponential-function, approximation, stirling-numbers

I want to find how these coefficients increase/decrease as $n$ increases:

$$ C_n = \frac{1}{n!} \left[(n+\alpha)^{n-\alpha-\frac{1}{2}}\right]$$

with $\alpha=\frac{1}{br-1}$ and $0\leq b,r \leq 1$.

I used the **Stirling's Approximation** factorial  $n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n} n^n e^{-n}$ and got:

$$ C_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n} n^n e^{-n}} \left[(n+\alpha)^{n-\alpha-\frac{1}{2}}\right]$$

I can't proceed any further. I would greatly appreciate any comment!

Comment: The Stirling approximation is : $$ n! \, \mathop{\sim} \limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \, \Big( \frac{n}{e} \Big)^{n} \sqrt{2 \pi n} $$

Comment: @jibounet you are right I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the reciprocal of Stirling's Asymptotic expansion as derived [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95454/13854):
$$
n!=\frac{n^n}{e^n}\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(1+\frac{1}{12n}+\frac{1}{288n^2}-\frac{139}{51840n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)
$$
we get
$$
\frac1{n!}=\frac{e^n}{n^n}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\left(1-\frac{1}{12n}+\frac{1}{288n^2}+\frac{139}{51840n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)
$$
Applying this to $\dfrac{(n+\alpha)^{n-\alpha-1/2}}{n!}$ and using the the log and exponential series for $\left(1+\frac\alpha{n}\right)^{n-\alpha-1/2}$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{(n+\alpha)^{n-\alpha-1/2}}{n!}\\
&=\frac{e^nn^{-\alpha-1}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(1+\frac\alpha{n}\right)^{n-\alpha-1/2}\left(1-\frac{1}{12n}+\frac{1}{288n^2}+\frac{139}{51840n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)\\[4pt]
&=\small\frac{e^{n+\alpha}n^{-\alpha-1}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(1-\frac{1+6\alpha+18\alpha^2}{12n}+\frac{1+12\alpha+144\alpha^2+456\alpha^3+324\alpha^4}{288n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)
\end{align}
$$

---

**Approximating $\boldsymbol{\left(1+\frac\alpha{n}\right)^{n-\alpha-1/2}}$**
$$
\begin{align}
&\left(n-\alpha-\frac12\right)\log\left(1+\frac\alpha{n}\right)\\
&=\left(n-\alpha-\frac12\right)\left(\frac\alpha{n}-\frac{\alpha^2}{2n^2}+\frac{\alpha^3}{3n^3}+O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)\right)\\
&=\alpha-\frac{\alpha+3\alpha^2}{2n}+\frac{3\alpha^2+10\alpha^3}{12n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Exponentiating, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac\alpha{n}\right)^{n-\alpha-1/2}
&=e^\alpha\left(1-\frac{\alpha+3\alpha^2}{2n}+\frac{9\alpha^2+38\alpha^3+27\alpha^4}{24n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)\right)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Take logarithms.  $\alpha$ can be any negative number; if you are interested in $n\gg-\alpha$, then $\ln(n+\alpha)\approx\ln n+(\alpha/n)$, so 
$$ \ln C_n\approx (n-\alpha-\frac12)(\ln n+\alpha/n)-(n+\frac12)\ln n+n-\ln(2\pi)/2\\
\approx(-\alpha-1)\ln n+n+\alpha-\ln(2\pi)/2\\
C_n\approx\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}n^{-\alpha-1}e^{n+\alpha}$$