# Prove that $1.49<\sum_{k=1}^{99}\frac{1}{k^2}<1.99$

Tags: summation

It can be proven by induction that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2}\leq2-\frac{1}{n}$$

From here, we can easily acquire the upper bound of the sum $$\sum_{k=1}^{99}\frac{1}{k^2}$$ letting $n=100$.

However, I am not quite sure about the lower bound. The standard method of constructing lower rectangles of unit width on the curve $y=\frac{1}{x^2}$ yields a lower bound of $0.99$, which isn't tight enough unfortunately. What could I do to achieve a sharper bound?

I know that as $n\rightarrow \infty$, the sum converges to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, but I feel that proving that result, just for this inequality, is a bit much.

Comment: One thing that might work is this: Don't apply any "method" for the first few terms - say 1 + 1/2^2 = 5/4, period. Apply whatever method to the sum of the _remaining_ terms. The point being those approximations are probably very bad for the first few terms...

Comment: Rectangular strips... you're on the right track! Just isolate the first strip and compare the remaining 98 with the curve. See my answer below.

Answer (score 10):

This approach as inspired by the Riemann sum. Basically, comparing the area of rectangular strips of unit width and height $\frac 1{k^2}$ with the area under the curve $y=\frac 1{k^2}$.

$$\begin{align}
1+\int_2^{100}\frac 1{k^2}dk<&\sum_{k=1}^{99}\frac 1{k^2}<1+\int_1^{99}\frac 1{k^2}dk\\
1.49<&\sum_{k=1}^{99}\frac 1{k^2}<1.99
\end{align}$$

Comment: +1: curiously the numerical values are the same than in my (telescoping sum) answer!

Comment: Well done!  A +1 ... this embedded the "spirit" of the question I believe

Comment: @Dr.MV - Thank you! Very kind of you to say so :)

Comment: @RaymondManzoni - Thank you! Yes, I did notice the curious coincidence. Or is it a coincidence at all?

Comment: Well of course not since $\int_n^{n+1}\frac {dk}{k^2}=\frac 1{n\,(n+1)}$ but neat anyway. Cheers,

Answer (score 7):

Hint: Telescoping and $$1+\sum_{k=2}^{99}\frac{1}{k\;(k+1)}<\sum_{k=1}^{99}\frac{1}{k^2}<1+\sum_{k=2}^{99}\frac{1}{k\;(k-1)}$$

Answer (score 6):

For the lower bound, just compute the first few terms:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{6}\frac{1}{k^2} \approx 1.4913 > 1.49
$$

The [exact value](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7B6%7D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bk%5E2%7D+) is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{6}\frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{5369}{3600} = 1.4913\bar8
$$

Comment: The 'common sense' answer

Answer (score 3):

Following the creative telescoping approach [I used to solve another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94722/stirlings-formula-proof/1409131?sfb=2#1409131),

$$\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{2m^2}+\frac{1}{6m^3}-\frac{1}{30m^5}\leq\sum_{n\geq m}\frac{1}{n^2}\leq\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{2m^2}+\frac{1}{6m^3}\tag{1}$$
hence:
$$\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{2m^2}+\frac{1}{6m^3}-\frac{1}{30m^5}\leq\sum_{n> m}\frac{1}{n^2}\leq\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{2m^2}+\frac{1}{6m^3}\tag{2}$$
and by setting $m=100$ we have:
$$ 0.009950166663\ldots\leq\frac{\pi^2}{6}-H_{100}^{(2)}\leq 0.009950166666\ldots\tag{3} $$
so:

> $$ \sum_{n=1}^{99}\frac{1}{n^2}=\color{red}{1.6348839}+E,\qquad |E|\leq \color{red}{10^{-9}}. \tag{4}$$