# What is the integer part of $\sum_{i=2}^{9999} \frac {1}{\sqrt i}?$

Tags: summation

What is the integer part of: $$\sum_{i=2}^{9999} \frac {1}{\sqrt {i}}$$

A short but tricky problem. Any help is welcome.

[Source](https://www.isical.ac.in/%7Eadmission/IsiAdmission/PreviousQuestion/BStat-BMath-UGA-2020.pdf)

Comment: What methods to approximate $$\sum_{k = 2}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$$ do you know?

Comment: Can you please explain. If you know the solution then you are welcome to write in the answer section. Then everyone can easily veiw it.

Comment: Try a Riemann sum. More precisely, lower and upper sums in a Darboux integral.

Comment: I have a feeling that integration might be useful

Comment: "No" to what? @DanielFischer's question is to know what you know.

Comment: Try to bound the sum from the top and from the bottom using an integral

Comment: @tatan can you please mention the source of this problem?

Comment: @newbie105 late but it is basically an ISI entrance question lol

Comment: @Buraian bruh ofc i know that. I wanted to know the real source ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Answer (score 26):

Creative telescoping gives another chance. Since:

$$ 2\left(\sqrt{i+1}-\sqrt{i}\right)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{i+1}+\sqrt{i}}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\leq\frac{2}{\sqrt{i}+\sqrt{i-1}}=2\left(\sqrt{i}-\sqrt{i-1}\right) $$
we have that $\sum_{i=2}^{9999}\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}$ is between $2\left(\sqrt{10000}-\sqrt{2}\right)$ and $2\left(\sqrt{9999}-1\right)$, hence:
$$ \left\lfloor\sum_{i=2}^{9999}\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\right\rfloor = \color{red}{197}.$$

Comment: Very creative manipulation of surds (+1). Interestingly it gives the same results as the integral approach.

Comment: It should, because the difference is the integral.

Comment: As always ... very cool!  +1

Answer (score 19):

Using an approach similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1409473/168053), we have

$$1+\int_2^{10000}\frac 1{\sqrt i}di\quad<\quad\sum_{i=1}^{9999}\frac 1{\sqrt i} \quad < \quad 1+\int_1^{9999}\frac 1{\sqrt{i}}di\\
\int_2^{10000}\frac 1{\sqrt i}di\quad<\quad\sum_{i=2}^{9999}\frac 1{\sqrt i} \quad < \quad \int_1^{9999}\frac 1{\sqrt{i}}di\\
2(\sqrt{10000}-\sqrt{2})\quad <\quad \sum_{i=2}^{9999}\frac 1{\sqrt i} \quad <\quad 2(\sqrt{9999}-\sqrt{1})\\
197.17\quad <\quad \sum_{i=2}^{9999}\frac 1{\sqrt i} \quad <\quad 197.99\\
\qquad \qquad\qquad \quad \Biggr\lfloor{\sum_{i=2}^{9999}\frac 1{\sqrt i}}\Biggr\rfloor\quad = \quad 197\qquad\blacksquare
$$

Comment: Almost identical to yesterday's!  +1 again

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1627949/bounding-series-with-integrals