# Bounding series with integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

Let $f(r)$ be a positive, continuous real function on $[N, \infty)$.
Is it always true that
$$
\int^{\infty}_{N+1} f(r) dr \leq \sum\limits_{i=N}^{\infty} f(i) \leq \int_{N-1}^{\infty} f(r) dr?
$$
What would I need in order it to be true?

Note: I see how to prove it when f(r) is strictly increasing or strictly decreasing, but I am looking for for some bounds that holds for a general increasing function.

Comment: I think you the lower bounds of your integrals are the opposite of what you meant. Were you looking for something more general than the Integral Test? http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/IntegralTest.aspx

Comment: Yes sorry that was a typo. Yes I am looking for something more general than the integral test.

Comment: you should ask in a first time when is it true that $\int_{aN}^{bN} f(x) dx \sim \sum_{n=aN}^{bN} f(n)$ when $N \to \infty$

Comment: When you say "positive definite" you just mean "positive", right? So why not just say "positive"? Saying "positive definite" sounds cool I suppose, but in fact "positive definite" means something that I'm pretty sure is not what you have in mind: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_function_on_a_group . You say you can prove those inequalities for _increasing_ positive $f$? How? (In fact the inequalities are true for increasing positive $f$, but for a silly reason: The sum and both integrals equal $0$.)

Comment: If $f$ is a general positive function it could be that $f$ is relatively large near the integers and very small elsewhere, so it could be the sum is $200$ and both integrals are less than $1$. Or the other way around, in which case the other way around...

Comment: @Dr.MV ??? The inequalities as stated hold for any non-negative non-increasing $f$. This is very easy to show.

Comment: @Dr.MV For one thing, there are no additional assumptions about integrability required.

Comment: @Dr.MV No, you do not need to assume $f$ is integrable. (Assuming that you mean Lebesgue integrable: If integrability were required we wouldn't be able to use the integral test to show $\sum1/n$ diverges. If you mean Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$: That follows from monotonicity. If you mean something else, what?)

Comment: @Dr.MV I read "You need additional assumptions on the monotinically decreasing nature of $f$" to mean we need something more than monotonically ddecreasing, some special sort of monotonicity. Which is evidently not what you meant, which is why I dropped that subtrhead when I did.

Comment: @Dr.MV I know that's what you meant. You said we need to assume $f$ is integrable. That is simply not true.

Comment: @Dr.MV Whether that looks strange to you or not, it's part of a _standard_ application of the integral test. As I pointed out several comments ago, it's perfectly legitimate to use the integral test to show $\sum1/n$ diverges. That's a _standard_ application, one on the first page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are presumably many different ways to generalize the usual Integral Test from calculus. So that we're on the same page, one form of the latter is as follows:

> **The Integral Test for Series:** Suppose $f$ is a monotonically decreasing, real-valued function on an interval $I = (a,\infty)$ such that $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in I$. Then for any choice of $N > a$, the series $\sum_{i=N}^\infty f(i)$ and integral $\int_{N}^\infty f(x)\,dx$ converge and diverge together. More precisely, $\int_{N+1}^\infty f(x)\,dx \leq \sum_{i=N}^\infty f(i) \leq \int_N^\infty f(x)\,dx$.

A "proof by pictures" which gives you the idea of why this works is summed up in the following two images (courtesy of [Paul's Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/IntegralTest.aspx)):

[image: $\sum_{i=N}^\infty f(i) \leq \int_N^\infty f(x)\,dx$]
[image: $\int_{N+1}^\infty f(x)\,dx \leq \sum_{i=N}^\infty f(i)$]

The key idea is that, for each $n \geq N$, the integral $\int_n^{n+1} f(x)\,dx$ is approximated from below by the rectangle of width $1$ and height $f(n+1)$ and from above by the rectangle of width $1$ and height $f(n)$. In the Integral Test, this is ensured by $f$ being positive and monotonically decreasing, but if you can find other conditions on $f$ that either (a) ensure these estimates still hold or (b) bound the value of $\int_n^{n+1} f(x)\,dx$ above and below by the values of $f$ at the integers in a reasonable way, then you've just found a new version of the integral test.

Going in another direction, the following generalized integral test is attributable to G.H. Hardy and can be really useful when the function $f$ is differentiable. Its proof is more complicated than the original integral test and relies on Abel summation, which you might not have seen before. Still, I'll present it here to give you an idea of the other "integral tests" that are out there. (A proof of this result can be found [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2305031?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) if you have JSTOR access.)

> **Hardy's Generalized Integral Test:** Suppose $f$ is a complex-valued function defined on an interval $[N,\infty)$ such that the derivative $f'$ exists on $[N,\infty)$ and satisfies $\int_N^x f'(t)\,dt = f(x) - f(N)$ for every $x \in [N,\infty)$. If $\int_N^\infty f'(t)\,dt$ is absolutely convergent, then the series $\sum_{i=N}^\infty f(i)$ and the integral $\int_N^\infty f(x)\,dx$ converge and diverge together.

Comment: That's interesting. I don't see how it needs anything as relatively sophisticated as Abel summation, seems simple. Because $\sum|f(i)-\int_i^{i+1}f|\le\sum\int_i^{i+1}|f'|<\infty$. (Ok, to nail down $\int_N^x$ for $x$ not an integer we also note that if $0<a<1$ then $|af(i)-\int_i^{i+a}f|\le\int_i^{i+a}|f'|\to0$ as $i\to\infty$, uniformly in $a$...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Good point! I believe in the brief (3 page) MAA note I linked to Abel summation is more used for convenience than anything else (as is often the case, I suppose). The author used it to first show, before proving either the integral or series converge, that $\lim_{M \to \infty}\left(\sum_{i=N}^M f(i) - \int_N^M f(x)\,dx \right)$ exists. I also didn't mention (to avoid confusion for OP) a fun fact: this works using Lebesgue integrals throughout and if $f'$ is only assumed to exist a.e. Accordingly, it includes the original integral test as a special case!

Comment: Sure about that? The hypotheses of Hardy's thing imply that $f$ is absolutely continuous, while the standard integral test does not even require that $f$ be continuous, just positive and non--increasing.

Comment: No, it's simply not true that $f$ monotone, continuous, differentiable almost everywhere, and $\int|f'|<\infty$ imply that $f(b)-f(a)=\int_a^bf'$. There exist functions satisfying all those conditions, and _also_ $f'=0$ almost everywhere, which are not constant. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Oh my gosh I haven't had enough coffee this morning. You're absolutely right, and I've deleted the offending comment. I'm not sure what the note's author was getting at regarding the original integral test then. Thanks for catching the error!