# Determine whether the series $\sum_\limits{k=1}^∞ \frac2{k^{3/2}}$ converges or diverges. If it converges, find the bounds for the sum of the series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Determine whether the series $\sum_\limits{k=1}^∞ \frac2{k^{3/2}}$ converges or diverges. If it converges, find the bounds for the sum of the series.

A) Converges, $\frac3{2}$ < $\sum_\limits{k=1}^∞ \frac2{k^{3/2}}$ < $\frac5{2}$

B) Converges, 2 < $\sum_\limits{k=1}^∞ \frac2{k^{3/2}}$ < 3

C) Converges, 4 < $\sum_\limits{k=1}^∞ \frac2{k^{3/2}}$ < 6

D) Converges, 6 < $\sum_\limits{k=1}^∞ \frac2{k^{3/2}}$ < 8

E) The series diverges

I know the series converges. Using p-Series, p=$\frac3{2}$ meaning that p>1 therefore the series converges. However, I don't know how to find the bounds for the sum of the series

Comment: A simple lower bound is obtained with exponent 2, which gives $\pi^2/3$

Comment: Have you tried [comparing to integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1627949/bounding-series-with-integrals) to deduce some bounds?

Comment: [Wolfram says](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*riemannzeta%281.5%29) it is 5.22475 ... but that probably doesn't count as an answer :-)

Comment: Just adding the first four terms already eliminates choices $ \mathbf{(A)} \ \text{and} \ \mathbf{(B)} \ $ ...  Looking at the terms where $ \ k^{3/2} \ $ is an integer (making the term rational) and considering how many terms of "comparable size" there are in between would give you a way to roughly estimate how the finite sums behave.  The question that remains is whether you ever get up to $ \ 6 \ $ ...

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

rough bounds are attain from the integral test for series with monotone terms:

$$f(n)+\int^n_1f(x)\,dx\leq \sum^n_{k=1}f(k)\leq f(1)+\int^n_1 f(x)\,dx$$
where $f(x)$ is monotone non increasing on $[1,\infty)$ and $f(x)\xrightarrow{x\rightarrow\infty}0$
Furthermore, if
$$d_n=\sum^n_{k=1}f(k) - \int^n_1f(x)\,dx,$$
then
$$ f(n+1)\leq d_{n+1}\leq d_n\leq f(1)$$
(See for example Apostol's analysis pp. 191).

In your case,  $f(x)=\frac{2}{x^{3/2}}$. There are better refinements to this bounds, but you may start with this and see how far you can go.