# What is integer part of $\sum_{j=2}^{100}\frac{1}{\sqrt{j}}$?

Tags: summation, contest-math

what is integer part of $$\sum_{j=2}^{100} \frac{1}{\sqrt{j}}= \frac{1}{\sqrt2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt3}+\frac{1}{\sqrt4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{100}}$$

I don’t have any idea how to approach this problem.

Comment: Here it is an idea: for any $n\geq 2$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is pretty close to $$ 2\left(\sqrt{n+1/2}-\sqrt{n-1/2}\right),$$ which is a telescopic term. Draw your conclusions. You just have to resolve a small uncertainty between 17 and 18.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I read your [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1410336/what-is-the-integer-part-of-sum-i-29999-frac-1-sqrt-i) but I still don’t get it ☹️

Comment: What is that you don't get? Maybe $$\sum_{n=a}^{b}\left( f(n+1)-f(n) \right) = f(b+1)-f(a) $$ ?

Comment: Contest math? Now we need to know the source. For questions from running contests are forbidden.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen it was asked today in IIIT-H undergrad entrance exam. Test is over btw.

Comment: Thanks, Fawad. That's ok!

Comment: Still, why are we supporting questions without any attempt from OP? Voted to close as off-topic.

Comment: This isn't rude behavior. This is what should be done. This isn't personal, but these type of question promote other users to ask homework questions.

Comment: yeah isn't this forum suppose students who can't solve a problem but tried? Why are you asking without attempt？

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a way by bounding the sum by integrals:

$$S = \sum_{j=2}^{100} \frac{1}{\sqrt{j}}= \frac{1}{\sqrt2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt3}+\frac{1}{\sqrt4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{100}} = 10 \sum_{j=2}^{100} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{j}{100}}}\frac{1}{100}$$
Now, you can bound the Riemann-sum on the right by two integrals:

$$10\int_{\frac{2}{100}}^{\frac{101}{100}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx < S < 10\int_{\frac{1}{100}}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx$$
You get
$$17 < 2(\sqrt{101}-\sqrt{2}) <S < 2(\sqrt{100}-1) = 18 \Rightarrow [S] = 17$$

Comment: Can I know how you bounded that series using Rimann-sum. I only know when $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}f(\frac{i}{n})=\int_0^1f(x)dx$ here $x=\frac{i}{n}$ thanks.

Comment: Just saw your question. Will answer later as I am travelling. Just as a quick help: The sim can be seen as an upper Darboux-sum for the left integral and as a lower Darboux-sum for the right integral. Note, that the interval of integration is slightly shifted for that reason. And note that the integrand is a postive decreasing function on the considered intervals.

Comment: That “darboux sum” is not my level stuff, I will read about it once I am free,I have exam in few days.

Comment: These are special Rieman-sums where you take instead of an arbitrary $f(\xi_i)$ for $\xi_i \in [x_i,x_{i+1}]$ always the minimum (lower Darboux-sum) or the maximum (upper Darboux-sum) of $f$ of the function on that small interval.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**. One may use, for $n\ge1$,
$$
 2\sqrt{n+1}-2\sqrt{n}= \int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}<\int_{n-1}^{n}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}=2\sqrt{n}-2\sqrt{n-1}.
$$ Then one may write
$$
\sum_{j=2}^{100} \frac{1}{\sqrt{j}}=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}+\sum_{j=3}^{100} \frac{1}{\sqrt{j}}
$$ and conclude using the above inequality for $n=3$ to $n=100$.