# Prove $\int_0^B e^\left(x^2\right) \;dx \sim \frac{e^\left(B^2\right)}{2B}$ where $B \to \infty$

Tags: calculus, integration

Prove that:

$$\int_0^B e^\left(x^2\right) \;dx \sim \frac{e^\left(B^2\right)}{2B}$$ where $$B \to \infty$$

We should prove the equivalence of the given integral to the expression in the right part.

It's obvious, that the integral in the given form cannot be expressed through known indefinite integrals. So let's try to apply a method of replacing a variable.

Write

$$
 \begin{matrix}
  u = x^2 \\
  dx = \frac{1}{2} u^\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right) du \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Now our integral looks like:

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^B e^\left(u\right) \sqrt{u} \;du$$

This is kinda cryptic. If we ask Wolfram to calculate indefinite integral for this integrand, we'll get:

$$\frac{1}{2}\int e^\left(u\right) \sqrt{u} \;du = e^u \sqrt{u} - \frac{1}{2} erfi(\sqrt{u}) + C$$

It's been calculated with a help of [erfi](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html) function.

I'm sure this way isn't close to the solution at all. So please give me at least a hint of how this integral can be presented in an equivalent form...

Comment: Why is there still an $x$ in the evaluated integral? Or does the $\sim$ mean something else?

Comment: sure you don't mean $e^{-x^2}$?

Comment: Despite the poor statement of the question, I answered it because I think there is use to the community.  That said, the OP really needs to put some thought into this and other questions.

Comment: Thank you all for replying! Sorry for the lack of information. I've updated the first post. And no, it's not $e^\left(-x^2\right)$.

Comment: The statement can also be proven using L'Hopital: $\lim_{B\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^B e^{x^2}{\rm d}x}{\frac{e^{B^2}}{2B}} = \lim_{B\to\infty}\frac{e^{B^2}}{e^{B^2} - \frac{e^{B^2}}{2B^2}} = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrate by parts:

$$\begin{align}\int_0^B dx \, e^{x^2} &= \underbrace{\int_0^1 dx \, e^{x^2}}_{C} + \int_1^B dx \, e^{x^2}\\ &= C + \int_1^B dx \,x \frac{e^{x^2}}{x} \\ &= C + \frac12 \left [\frac{e^{x^2}}{x} \right ]_1^B + \frac12 \int_1^B dx \, \frac{e^{x^2}}{x^2}\\ &=  \underbrace{C - \frac{e}{2}}_{\text{constant which is dominated by other terms}} +  e^{B^2} \left [\frac1{2 B} + O \left ( \frac1{B^3}\right ) \right ]  \end{align}$$

Thus, as $B \to \infty$, the integral behaves as

$$\int_0^B dx \, e^{x^2} =  e^{B^2} \left [\frac1{2 B} + O \left ( \frac1{B^3}\right ) \right ] $$

Comment: Thank you so much! I've just noticed the notebook said $\frac{e^{B^2}}{2B}$. :)

Comment: (+1) In this case, I believe you get the same asymptotic expansion by continuing the integration by parts.

Answer (score 3):

Using the same approach as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95454), but leaving out the details, which are handled in a similar fashion, we get the asymptotic expansion
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^xe^{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t
&=e^{x^2}\int_0^xe^{t^2-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=e^{x^2}\int_0^xe^{-2tx+t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=xe^{x^2}\int_0^1e^{-(2t-t^2)x^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&\sim xe^{x^2}\int_0^\infty e^{-2ux^2}\left(1+u+\frac32u^2+\frac52u^3+\frac{35}8u^4+O\left(u^5\right)\right)\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\left(\frac1{2x}+\frac1{4x^3}+\frac3{8x^5}+\frac{15}{16x^7}+\frac{105}{32x^9}+O\left(\frac1{x^{11}}\right)\right)e^{x^2}
\end{align}
$$
where $2u=2t-t^2$.

Comment: +1: Yep, you get the same expansion by integrating by parts.

Comment: As a check, I gave `Series[Integrate[Exp[t^2],{t,0,x}],{x,Infinity,10}]` to Mathematica 8 (I've not tried Mathematica 10). It returned what I have above, but added a constant $-i\frac{\sqrt\pi}2$ to the answer. While it is true that any constant term is $O\left(\frac1{x^{11}}\right)e^{x^2}$, the question is why would an imaginary constant be added? I assume it is a leftover from the complex method it uses to compute the asymptotic expansion.

Comment: absolutely.  $Erfi[z] = -i Erf[i z]$ in Mathematica-speak, so no surprise when its Taylor-about-infinity expansion algorithm trips over itself.