# Bound on the value of $\binom{n }{n/2}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics

I know the value of $\binom{n}{r}$ is maximum for $r=n/2$ if $n$ is even. I am in need to calculate the value of $\binom{n}{n/2}$. 
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+\ldots+\binom{n}{n/2}+\ldots,+\binom{n}{n}=2^n
\end{align*}
What is the value of $\binom{n}{n/2}$? any idea how to calculate it. I think it is order  of $2^ n$. Please help me regarding this

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient.

Comment: Some proofs [there](https://www3.nd.edu/~dgalvin1/pdf/bertrand.pdf)

Comment: Also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58560/elementary-central-binomial-coefficient-estimates

Answer (score 2):

The central term is the largest one and so $2^n \le (n+1){{n} \choose {n/2}}$.
Therefore
$$
\frac{2^n}{n+1} \le {{n} \choose {n/2}} \le 2^n
$$

It is true that
$$
{n \choose {n/2}}\sim {\frac  {2^{n}}{{\sqrt  {\pi {n/2}}}}}{\text{ as }}n\rightarrow \infty 
$$
This follows from [Wallis' product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product) and from [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Comment: @Ihf in second line is it "$2n$" or "$n$"?..can you elaborate the last line when n tends to infinity? how you derived that term?

Comment: @ViX28: It goes to infinity as $n$ goes to infinity, but grows more slowly than $2^n$, i.e. is $o(2^n)$

Comment: @ViX28, fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You my provide tight bounds for a central binomial coefficient through [Stirling's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94722/stirlings-formula-proof/1409131#1409131).
For instance,

> $$-\frac{1}{64n\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}\leq  \log\,\left(\binom{2n}{n}\frac{\sqrt{\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{4}\right)}}{4^n}\right)\leq -\frac{1}{64n(n+1)} \tag{1}$$

holds for every $n\geq 1$. That gives that $\binom{2n}{n}$ essentially behaves like $\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{4}\right)}}.$
An even more accurate approximation is:

> $$\forall n\geq 1,\qquad \frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\approx\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{32n}\right)}}.\tag{2}$$