# Summation using telescopic method

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

How can I find the telescopic sum of this summation using the telescopic method?
$${\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over (2n+1)^{2}}}$$

Comment: May I ask why you want to use such a method?

Comment: Given that the answer is $\pi^2/8$ that will require some *very* ingenious telescoping...

Comment: I think you're better off just noticing that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2} \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$$ if all you're doing is trying to show that the sum is convergent.

Comment: Perhaps not 'true telescoping' but $\;\displaystyle \sum_{k = 1}^\infty {1 \over k^{2}}=\sum_{n = 0}^\infty {1 \over (2n+1)^{2}}+{1 \over (2n+2)^{2}}\;$ should help if you know the series at the left (and thus at the right...)

Comment: I have solved a lot of summation using Telescopic method but this seems a bit complicated, this is why I asked whether it could be done easily or not. How did you guess the answer $\pi^/ 8$ easily? :O

Comment: From the [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) we have $\;\dfrac{\pi^2}6=\zeta(2)=S+\dfrac{\zeta(2)}4$. A neat [direct proof](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Polya/07468342.di020759.02p00026.pdf) was exposed by Zagier (see $(3)$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot directly compute such series (and get $\frac{\pi^2}{8}$) by creative telescoping, but you may use creative telescoping to provide tight approximations of its value. For instance,
$$ \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2} - \color{green}{\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+3)}} = \frac{2}{(2n+1)^2(2n+3)} \tag{1}$$
and the green term is a telescopic term, hence
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2} &=& \color{green}{\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+3)}}+2\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2(2n+3)}\\&=&\color{green}{\frac{1}{2}}+2\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2(2n+3)}\end{eqnarray*}\tag{2}$$
Now we may approximate $\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2(2n+3)}$ with a telescopic term, like $\color{green}{\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}-\frac{1}{(2n+3)^2}\right)}$, and continue the above procedure, producing an accurate rational approximation of $\frac{\pi^2}{8}$:

$$ \frac{\pi^2}{8}=\color{green}{\frac{4}{3}}-\frac{8}{3}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(4n^2+8n+3)^3}\tag{3}$$
and an accelerated series:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}=\color{blue}{\frac{9}{4}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2\binom{2n}{n}}}.\tag{4}$$

The exact value of the series can be computed, for instance, by applying [Parseval's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem) to
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\sin((2n+1)x)}{2n+1} \tag{5}$$
that is the Fourier series of a [rectangle wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave). Another proof lies in [this historical thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/617710/44121). It is interesting to point out that the above technique (creative telescoping) also provides [a rather short proof of Stirling's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1409131/44121), for instance.