# Proving the result $294!<100^{300}<295!$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-comparison

> Proving $294!<100^{300}<295!$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ I have used Stirling Approximation $$n!\approx \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\cdot \sqrt{2\pi n}$$

Put $n=294$ and $n=295$,

$$294!\approx \left(\frac{294}{e}\right)^{294}\cdot \sqrt{2\pi \cdot 294}$$

and $$295!\approx \left(\frac{295}{e}\right)^{295}\cdot \sqrt{2\pi \cdot 295}$$

Now i did not understand hoe can i solve it, Help required, Thanks

Comment: Switch to logarithms in order to avoid dealing with huge numbers. Use Stirling's formula as $$\log n! \approx n\log n-n+\frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi n)$$

Comment: And $\frac12\log(2\pi n)$ is probably insignificant.

Comment: If you choose $\log_{10}$, you can easily very the double-inequality.

Comment: @SimpleArt Probably yes, but why taking this risk ?

Comment: @Peter If we ignore that part and prove the second half inequality, it'd be much much easier.

Comment: Strictly speaking, using the Stirling's approximation, we also need to estimate the error. An induction proof would be nice, not sure whether it will work.

Comment: @Peter It'll underapproximate $295!$, so we don't really have to worry for that part.

Comment: @Peter: we also have an inequality: $$\log n!=n\log n-n+\frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi n)+E(n)$$ where $E(n)$ is bounded between $\frac{1}{12n+1}$ and $\frac{1}{12n}$, see http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1409131/44121

Comment: SimpleArt and Jack D'Aurizio :  I know, I only wanted to mention it.

Comment: The logarithms of the involved terms are roughly $1381,1381.5$ and $1386.5$, so we do not need to worry about $E(n)$, that is way less than $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Rate_of_growth_and_approximations_for_large_n) tells us that
$$
n\ln \left({\frac {n}{e}}\right)+1\leq \ln n!\leq (n+1)\ln \left({\frac {n+1}{e}}\right)+1
$$
Dividing by $\ln 100$ gives
$$
299.005 < \log_{100} 294! < 301.25
\\
300.24 < \log_{100} 295! < 302.48
$$
which is almost what is needed, except for the upper bound for $\log_{100} 294!$.

The actual values are
$$
\log_{100} 294! \approx 299.82
\\
\log_{100} 295! \approx 301.06
$$
and so we do need tight bounds to solve the question.

Using
$$
{\sqrt {2\pi n}}\left({\frac {n}{e}}\right)^{n}<n!<{\sqrt {2\pi n}}\left({\frac {n}{e}}\right)^{n}e^{\frac {1}{12n}}
$$
and taking logs as before we get
$$
299.82240 < \log_{100} 294! < 299.82247
$$
which does it.