# If $n$ is a positive integer, Prove that $\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{3^2}+\dotsb+\frac1{n^2}\lt\frac{2329}{3600}.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

If $n$ is a positive integer, Prove that

$$\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{3^2}+\dotsb+\frac1{n^2}\lt\frac{2329}{3600}.$$

please don't refer to the famous  $1+\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{3^2}+\dotsb=\frac{\pi^2}6$.

I am looking a method that doesn't use $\text{“}\pi\text{''}.$

Unfortunately, I know and tried only $\text{“}\pi\text{''}$ method.

Comment: what has been tried ?

Comment: I know only.Unfortunately $\pi$ method.

Comment: What is the context, in particular why $2329/3600$ and not $2322/3600$ for which the inequality is still true?

Comment: Why _not_ just use one of the many methods showing that $\sum n^{-2} = \pi^2/6$?

Comment: @dxiv How did you find $2322$?

Comment: @Student How did you find $2329$?

Comment: @Student $\;$ [$\lceil (\pi^2 / 6 - 1) \cdot 3600 \rceil$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(pi%5E2+%2F+6+-+1)+*+3600). Your turn now to shed some light on why $2329$ was chosen, instead.

Comment: @T.Gunn dear friend, this is a question, which that we must find the "secret" in  $\frac{2329}{3600}$. You can try the inequality is true.I tried.

Comment: @Student You can try the inequality with $\frac{2322}{3600}$ too. That's also true.

Comment: How did you find $2322$ ??

Comment: @Student:  dxiv showed a link to Wolfram Alpha that finds $2322$

Comment: $$ \left( \frac{\pi^2} 6 - 1\right) \cdot 3600 = 2321.76264\ldots $$

Comment: Ok, I didnt think, there is a "contact" between  my question and Wolfram aplha..Ok.How to prove that, $2322$ without $"\pi"$ method. ??This is important question for me.

Comment: @Student Where does the question come from?

Comment: you could prove it for n=k and then prove it follows for n=k+1 . The problem I see is that 1 is a positive integer, and I can't see it holding there.

Comment: Really, I dont understand you..and Why downvoted the question?? If we dont know answer, we must be downvoted, dear friends??And in the exam**We cann't use Wolfram Alpha**

Comment: @Student The formula in my previous comment was a direct answer to your question `How did you find 2322`. You don't *need* WA to find $2322$, you could just as well find it with pen and paper using the $\pi \simeq 355/113$ majorization. P.S. You still haven't provided any clues as to where *your* $2329$ came from. If this was an exam question, it helped if you gave some context about what and at what level.

Comment: @Michael Hardy  If you want ,You can look MathLife's solution..

Comment: @dxiv Please look at MathLife"s solution..and you can see where did $"2329"$ come from.

Answer (score 8):

I like this kind of numerical challenges. Let us exploit creative telescoping.
 For any $n\geq 2$ we have
$$ \frac{1}{n^2}-\left[\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right]=\frac{1}{n^2(n+1)}\tag{1} $$
$$ \frac{1}{n^2(n+1)}-\left[\frac{1}{2n^2}-\frac{1}{2(n+1)^2}\right]=\frac{1}{2n^2(n+1)^2}\tag{2} $$
$$ \frac{1}{2n^2(n+1)^2}-\left[\frac{1}{6n^3}-\frac{1}{6(n+1)^3}\right]=-\frac{1}{6n^3(n+1)^3}\tag{3} $$
$$ \frac{1}{6n^3(n+1)^3}-\left[\frac{1}{30n^5}-\frac{1}{30(n+1)^5}\right]=\frac{5n^2+5n+1}{30n^5(n+1)^5}\tag{4}$$
$$ \frac{5n^2+5n+1}{30n^5(n+1)^5}< \frac{1}{42 n^7}-\frac{1}{42(n+1)^7}\tag{5} $$
hence by setting $g(n)=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2n^2}+\frac{1}{6n^3}-\frac{1}{30n^5}$ we have
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \zeta(2)-1=\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{1}{n^2} &=& \sum_{n\geq 2}\left[g(n)-g(n+1)\right]+\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{5n^2+5n+1}{30n^5(n+1)^5}\\ &<& g(2)+\frac{1}{42\cdot 2^7}=\color{red}{\frac{5779}{8960}}<\frac{2322}{3600}.\tag{6}\end{eqnarray*} $$

The same technique [proves Stirling's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1409131/44121) and the "acceleration formula"
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2} = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{3}{n^2\binom{2n}{n}}\tag{7} $$
leading to the more accurate approximation $\zeta(2)-1\approx \frac{51077}{79200}$.

---

There also is a simple and accurate lower bound. By choosing $h(x)=\frac{6x-3}{6x^2-6x+2}$ we have $\frac{1}{x^2}\geq h(x)-h(x+1)$ for any $x\geq 2$, with the difference behaving like $\frac{1}{9x^6}$. It follows that
$$ \zeta(2)-1\geq \color{red}{\frac{9}{14}} = h(2).\tag{8}$$
By selecting $k(x)=\frac{60x^2-60x+31}{60x^3-90x^2+66x-18}$ we get $\zeta(2)-1\leq \frac{151}{234}$, simpler but less accurate than $(6)$.

Comment: you are genius, really...ıs $\frac{2329}{3600}$ is absurd fraction?

Comment: @Student: it is not more *absurd* than $\frac{5779}{8960}$, and $\frac{643}{997}$ is *stranger* and *more accurate* than both.

Comment: Sorry, Other users criticize me, $\frac{2329}{3600}$ is very absurd.

Comment: @Student: *To be happy you have to learn hearing only the right criticisms*, Master Yoda said.

Comment: Using $\frac1{n^2}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac1h\left[\frac1n-\frac1{n+h}\right]$ I get $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac1hH_h$$ Hopefully you can use this more creatively than I can.  Good night!

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: by de l'Hopital rule that is the same as stating $\zeta(2)=\psi'(1)$, but I am not aware of slick methods for approximating $\psi'$ other than exploiting creative telescoping / the EML formula. Converting everything to an integral and exploiting Beuker-like techniques should not be more efficient, but maybe I am wrong about that, thanks for the suggestion and good night to you too.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio what if you were asked to show that $\zeta(2)<\dfrac{129}{200}$

Comment: @Raffaele You mean $\zeta(2)-1<\frac{129}{200}$?  If so, you can use my answer, changing the upper bound to the last sum to $123$ or higher, though that makes it rather brute force.

Comment: @Raffaele: nothing to change since $\frac{5779}{8960}<\frac{129}{200}$.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio dear Jack, I found a way, for this problem.But  I have no computer and i know latex very bad..If I write with hand, can you help me for exchange to latex?? And my english knowledge olso bad..If could you please?..

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio https://files.acrobat.com/a/preview/9e8dd36e-4e3b-489c-afd0-d427e690fd6e

Comment: @MathLife: I took the liberty to summarize your approach. Things here tend to get appreciated if they are extremely short OR extremely long, I hope you are happy with the outcome.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio Dear Jack, Your edit is really impressive.in a Single line..I have to admit, I could not understand you for your **own solution.** This is really hard..I will try again for understanding..(and thanks for +1)

Answer (score 5):

A viable approach is also to apply a "delayed" creative telescoping based on the identity $\frac{1}{n^2}<\frac{1}{n^2-1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$. This approach leads to

$$ \zeta(2)-1<\left(\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n>5}\left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=\frac{2329}{3600} $$
in a single line.

Comment: This is not "stupid" at all, it is a very efficient approach, indeed. (+1)

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio  I am absolutely happy.!! This is amazing. Thank you so much for help me!.. You did a great job..!

Answer (score 2):

Let $\displaystyle S = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac 1 {n^2}.\,$ A simple integral test shows $S<\infty.$

Let $T$ be some number a little bit bigger than $S.$ Then
\begin{align}
& \frac 1 {2^2} + \cdots + \frac 1 {n^2} \\[10pt]
< {} & \frac 1 {2^2} + \cdots + \frac 1 {n^2} + \int_n^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2} \\[10pt]
= {} & \left(\frac 1 {2^2} + \cdots + \frac 1 {n^2} \right) + \frac 1 n \tag 1 \\[10pt]
< {} & S + \frac 1 n \\[10pt]
< {} & T \text{ if $n$ is big enough.}
\end{align}
This shows $\displaystyle \frac 1 {2^2} + \cdots + \frac 1 {n^2} < T$ if $n$ is big enough, but that sum is smaller if $n$ is smaller; therefore that inequality holds without any qualification on the size of $n.$

Thus we only need to know how big $T$ needs to be, or how small $T$ can be. I think maybe if you take $n=500$ then line $(1)$ might show that $T=2329/3600$ can serve.

This is computation-intensive. Maybe there's also an intelligent way to do it.

Comment: I think the OP does not deserve an answer like *add $1000$ terms, so that the approximation error is less than $10^{-3}$*. There are plenty of "slicker" approaches.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio : As I said, there may also be an intelligent way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

For any natural $n$, we have

$$S_1=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac1{k^2}>\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1{k^2}$$

Likewise, consider the following alternating sum:

$$S_2=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k^2}$$

And see that we have

$$S_1+S_2=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1+(-1)^k}{k^2}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac2{(2k)^2}=\frac12+\frac12S_1$$

Thus, we have

$$S_1=1-2S_2$$

Furthermore, it is easy to see that

$$S_2>\sum_{k=2}^{23}\frac{(-1)^k}{k^2}$$

And thus,

$$S_1<1-2\sum_{k=2}^{23}\frac{(-1)^k}{k^2}<\frac{2329}{3600}$$

Not a terrible sum to evaluate there.

Answer (score 0):

approximate by telescoping series. 
$\left(\sum_{k=2}^{20} \dfrac1{k^2}\right)+(\frac1{20}-\frac1{21})+(\frac1{21}-\frac1{22})+・・・(\frac1{n-1}-\frac1n)=.62976+\frac1{20}-\frac1n=.64616-\frac1n<0.6469\dot4=\frac{2329}{3600}$.

Also $16$ instead of 20 holds.

Answer (score -3):

The simplest approach is to approximate the sum by the integral. The crude way of doing it just uses the fact that $1/x^2$ is a decreasing function, so the integral from $k$ to $k+1$ is bigger than $1/(k+1)^2.$ to make it sharper, one notes that since $1/x^2$ is convex, the integral is actually bigger than $\frac12(1/n^2 + 1/(n+1)^2).$

Comment: Such crude approximation is not enough to reach the required accuracy. The difference between $\zeta(2)-1$ and $\frac{2339}{3600}$ is $\approx 5\cdot 10^{-3}$.

Comment: This solution only works for about $n<10$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio have you tried? The function $1/x^2$ is very close to linear for any $n>7.$ Maybe you actually have to integrate the quadratic exactly for the first few terms (the exact integral is $1/(n(n+1)^2).$)

Comment: @IgorRivin: exploiting convexity is the same as following my approach and stopping at $(2)$ or $(3)$. Not enough.

Comment: Have you tried this approach?  And btw, $1/x^2$ being convex implies the integral is less than the trapezoidal sum.  Unless you offshift it... but this still isn't nearly enough.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: I guess Igor intended to exploit the Hermite-Hadamard inequality that gives a lower- and an upper-bound at the same time, but that does not really work for large values of $n$.