# Lower bound on $\log(1-x)$ for $x$ near $0$

Tags: calculus, inequality, logarithms

I'm looking for lower bounds on the function $x\mapsto \log(1-x)$ with $0\leq x<1$. Actually, I only need $x\in [0,c]$, $c<1$.

So far, I've tried using Taylor expansion with integral remainder but since all derivatives are negative, I can only get an upper-bound.

Comment: There is no lower bound.  log(1- x) goes to negative infinity as x goes to 1.  For your other question, with c< 1 (which is not at all the same as your first question) the lower bound is log(1- c).

Comment: @user247327: what do you have against functions with the same behaviour which are less than $\log(1-x)$ on $[0,1)$?

Comment: $$\sqrt{1-x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$$ is a chance, for instance. There are better ones, among rational or algebraic approximations.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio : do you think it's possible to get a lower bound with polynomial/Taylor-like form when $x$ is close to $0$ (or less than $\frac{1}{2}$ let's say) ? Some kind of dual bound of this one : $x-x^2/2 \leq \log(1+x)\leq x-x^2/2 + x^3/3$.

Comment: @anonymus: if you fix $c\in(0,1)$, you may achieve something similar over $[0,c]$, with the involved coefficients depending on $c$. Just bound $\frac{1}{1+x}$ by convexity and apply termwise integration. What is the purpose of producing such inequality, if I may ask?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio : I'm studying the asymptotic behaviour of a big sum. Since it is a sum, I can't just substitute the terms by their asymptotic approximations. I need to (lower+upper) bound the terms of my sum "by hand".

Comment: @anonymus: If I am right about the problem you are currently approaching, I guess you may find this answer inspiring: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1409131/44121

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio : thank you for the suggestion. I encounter binomial coefficient (so naturally, factorial approximation). But so far, I can't really see how it is going to help me. Anyway, I'm pretty sure that my question has some answer.

Comment: How good a bound do you need? For every $c \in (0,1)$ there is a $K_c$ with $-K_c x \leqslant \log (1-x) \leqslant -x$ on $[0,c]$. For many things, that's good enough. If you need something better, $$-\sum_{k = 1}^{m-1} \frac{x^k}{k} - \frac{x^m}{m(1-x)}$$ may do it for a suitable $m$.

Comment: @anonymus Did the comments and/or the answer settle your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this very handy cheatsheet of inequalities](http://www.lkozma.net/inequalities_cheat_sheet/ineq.pdf):
for $0\leq x<1$,
$$\begin{align}
\ln(1-x) \geq \frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x}} \tag{$\dagger$}
\end{align}$$

---

*Proof.*
let $f$ be defined on $(-1,1)$ by $f(x) = \ln(1-x) + \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x}}$. It is $\mathcal{C}^1$ on its domain, $f(0)=0$, and
$$
f'(x) = \frac{2-x-2\sqrt{1-x}}{2(1-x)^{3/2}}\,.
$$
It is easy to see that, for $-1< x<1$, $f'(x)\geq 0$ (it suffices to analyze the numerator, as the denominator is positive). This gives the inequality.

Comment: Thank you @Clement C. , this cheatsheet is AWESOME !

Comment: Glad you like it! It's been taped to my wall since I found it.