# Deriving the fact that the approximation $\log(n!) \approx n\log(n) - n + \frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi n)$ is $O(1/n)$.

Tags: asymptotics, factorial

I get to begin with Stirling's approximation, for any $C \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, there exists some $N \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ such that $N > C$ and for all $n > N$:
\begin{align*}
    &\quad \left|n! - \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{n}\right| \leq C \left|\frac{1}{n}\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\right| \\
    &\Rightarrow -C \frac{1}{n}\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n \leq n! - \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{n} \leq C \frac{1}{n}\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n \\
    &\Rightarrow -C \frac{1}{n}\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n + \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{n} \leq n! \leq C \frac{1}{n}\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n + \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{n} \\
    &\Rightarrow \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\left(-C \frac{1}{n} + 1\right) \leq n! \leq \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\left(C \frac{1}{n} + 1\right)
\end{align*}

Now we are in a position to make further manipulations:

\begin{align*}
&\quad \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\left(-C \frac{1}{n} + 1\right) \leq n! \leq \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\left(C \frac{1}{n} + 1\right) \\
&\{\text{$\log$ is monotonic}\} \\
&\Rightarrow \log\left(\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\left(-C \frac{1}{n} + 1\right)\right) \leq \log\left(n!\right) \leq \log\left(\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\left(C \frac{1}{n} + 1\right)\right) \\
&\{\text{take the average of the upper ($U(n)$) and lower bounds ($L(n)$)}\} \\
&\{\text{$\log(n!) \approx f(n)$ means $|f(n) - \log(n!)| \leq K \left[U(n) - L(n)\right]$, where $0 \leq K \leq 1$}\} \\
&\Rightarrow \log(n!) \approx \frac{1}{2}\log\left(\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\left(C \frac{1}{n} + 1\right)\right) + \frac{1}{2}\log\left(\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\left(-C \frac{1}{n} + 1\right)\right) \\
&\Rightarrow \log(n!) \approx \frac{1}{2}\left(\log\left(\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\left(C \frac{1}{n} + 1\right)\right) + \log\left(\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\left(-C \frac{1}{n} + 1\right)\right)\right) \\
&\Rightarrow \log(n!) \approx \frac{1}{2}\log\left((\sqrt{2\pi n})^2\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{2n}\left(C \frac{1}{n} + 1\right)\left(-C \frac{1}{n} + 1\right)\right) \\
&\Rightarrow \log(n!) \approx \frac{1}{2}\log\left(2\pi n\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{2n}\left(\frac{-C^2}{n^2} + 1\right)\right) \\
&\Rightarrow \log(n!) \approx \frac{1}{2}\log\left(2\pi n\right) +  \frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{n^{2n}}{e^{2n}}\right) + \frac{1}{2}\log\left(1 - \frac{C^2}{n^2}\right) \\
&\Rightarrow \log(n!) \approx \frac{1}{2}\log\left(2\pi n\right) +  \frac{1}{2}\log\left(n^{2n}\right) - \frac{1}{2}\log\left(e^{2n}\right) + \frac{1}{2}\log\left(1 - \frac{C^2}{n^2}\right) \\
&\Rightarrow \log(n!) \approx \frac{1}{2}\log\left(2\pi n\right) +  n\log\left(n\right) - n\log\left(e\right) + \frac{1}{2}\log\left(1 - \frac{C^2}{n^2}\right) \\
&\Rightarrow \log(n!) \approx  n\log\left(n\right) - n + \frac{1}{2}\log\left(2\pi n\right) + \frac{1}{2}\log\left(1 - \frac{C^2}{n^2}\right)
\end{align*}

From here I could expand $\log(1 + x)$ about $x = 0$ (note that $0 < \frac{C^2}{n^2} < 1$, as $C < n$, and $0 < n, C$, and also $C^2/n^2$ is pretty close to $0$ most of the time, as $n > C$). The first term of the Taylor series expansion for $\log(1 + x)$ about $x = 0$ is simply $x$.

\begin{align*}
&\quad \log(n!) \approx  n\log\left(n\right) - n + \frac{1}{2}\log\left(2\pi n\right) + \frac{1}{2}\log\left(1 - \frac{C^2}{n^2}\right) \\
&\Rightarrow \log(n!) \approx  n\log\left(n\right) - n + \frac{1}{2}\log\left(2\pi n\right) - \frac{C^2}{2n^2}
\end{align*}

But this seems to suggest my error is $O(1/n^2)$? Isn't this approximation supposed to be $O(1/n)$? Please advise on where I went wrong.

Comment: (In your last line you probably want to say $\Theta(1/n)$, since $O(1/n^2)$ _is_ technically (a subset of) $O(1/n)$; but yes, the next term should be $1/(12n)$. Your error comes when you take the average of the upper and lower bounds, because they _are_ approximations rather than exact terms, and there's no reason to believe that the real result lies 'precicely' in the middle. The best you can 'actually' do there (and that step is wholly unnecessary) is to say that the multiplying factor there is $\approx (1-O(1/n))(1+O(1/n))$ and this is only in $1+O(1/n)$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I don't see how I assume that the result is precisely in the middle? See how I define $\log(n!) \approx f(n)$.

Comment: You say 'take the average of the upper and lower boundss', and _that_ average is where you lose the $1/n$ term, but you don't explain why you feel like you can take that average or what that average does.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94722/stirlings-formula-proof/1409131#1409131

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Very vaguely related, as I start with what question is attempting to prove?

Comment: @user89: your claim is indeed trivial by creative telescoping, so that is not *vaguely* related, it is related in a pretty tight way.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio cool? I am not using creative telescoping, or the general gamma function though, so its difficult for me to interpret that answer. I am not saying its not very valuable, but I can't make use of it, because I lack the knowhow. Still, it would be good for future persons who visit this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you've written here is 'correct' — but let's take a closer look at what it means.  Your definition of $\approx$ says: "$\log(n!)\approx f(n)$ means that $\left|f(n)-\log(n!)\right|\leq K (U(n)-L(n))$ for some $0\leq K\leq 1$".  And we have $L(n) = n\log n-n+\log(2\pi n)+\log(1-\frac Cn)$ and $U(n)=n\log n-n+\log(2\pi n)+\log(1+\frac Cn)$.  So the *difference* between these terms — the bound you've put on the 'quality' of $\approx$ — is $\log(1+\frac Cn)-\log(1-\frac Cn)$. But the best you can say about this is that it's $O(\frac1n)$, so that's what your result is: $\log(n!)\in n\log n-n+\log(2\pi n)-\frac{C^2}{2n^2}+O(\frac1n)$.  And now there's no point in including the $-\frac {C^2}{2n^2}$ term, because the $O(\frac1n)$ term 'overwhelms' it.

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. Can you point me to a resource that I should read to understand why $\log(1 - (1/n))$ is $O(1/n)$?

Comment: @user89 I can't point to a specific resource, but probably the most useful is just the Taylor series, which says that $\log(1+x)\in x+O(x^2)$ (as $x\to 0$).

Comment: Right, thanks! That totally makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing justifies that a function is equivalent to the average of the left and right-hand sides in an inequality.

$n^2<n^3<n^4$ but that doesn't make $n^3\sim \dfrac{n^2+n^4}{2}$.

Just after you use the monotonicity of $\log$ you can already conclude by saying that $\log(1+\frac{C}{n})\leq \frac{C}{n}$.

Comment: I do not ever claim that a function is *equivalent* to the average of the left and right hand sides of the inequality. I simply claim that the function is close to the average of the left and right hand sides of the inequality. How close? I give a conservative estimate of at most |upperbound - lowerbound| close (but it is more likely to be at most 1/2 |upperbound - lowerbound| away).

Comment: All right. The second part of my answer still applies though.

Comment: @user89 If it's 1/2 (upperbound-lowerbound) away, that difference is still $\theta(1/n)$; both your upper and lower bounds are that far away from their center.