# How to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\Gamma(n/2+1)}\int_{0}^{n} t^{n/2}e^{-t}dt = 1$?

Tags: integration, limits, gamma-function

How can we prove
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\Gamma(n/2+1)}\int_{0}^{n}  t^{n/2}e^{-t}dt = 1$$
?

We ran experiments on MATLAB, it seems the statement is true.

Comment: I think this is equivalent to proving that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\Gamma(n/2+1)}\int_0^n t^{n/2} e^{-t}\,dt = 1 $.

Comment: Have you tried using the definition of the Gamma function? (For instance, as given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function )

Comment: @Zachary Yes. They are equivalent since $\Gamma(z) = \Gamma(z,x) + \gamma(z,x)$. But still how to prove that?

Comment: @user676464327 Yes. I know the definition. This question is concerning (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) and the gamma function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the maximum of $t^{n/2}e^{-t/2}=e^{-\frac t2+\frac n2\log(t)}$ occurs at $t=n$, we get that
$$
t^{n/2}e^{-t/2}\le n^{n/2}e^{-n/2}\tag1
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
1-\frac1{\Gamma(n/2+1)}\int_0^n t^{n/2}e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t
&=\frac1{\Gamma(n/2+1)}\overbrace{\int_n^\infty t^{n/2}e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t}^{\Gamma(n/2+1,n)}\tag2\\
&\le\frac{\left(\frac ne\right)^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2+1)}\int_n^\infty e^{-t/2}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag3\\
&=\frac{\left(\frac ne\right)^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2+1)}2e^{-n/2}\tag4\\
&\le\frac{\left(\frac ne\right)^{n/2}}{\sqrt{\pi n}\left(\frac n{2e}\right)^{n/2}}2e^{-n/2}\tag5\\
&=\frac2{\sqrt{\pi n}}\left(\frac2e\right)^{n/2}\tag6
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(2)$: $\Gamma(n/2+1)=\int_0^\infty t^{n/2}e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t$ is the [Gamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)
$\phantom{\text{(2):}}$ $\Gamma(n/2+1,n)=\int_n^\infty t^{n/2}e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t$ is the [Incomplete Gamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function)
$(3)$: apply $(1)$
$(4)$: integrate
$(5)$: Stirling is an underapproximation (see [Theorem $4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3268210))
$(6)$: simplify

Thus,
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{1-\frac2{\sqrt{\pi n}}\left(\frac2e\right)^{n/2}\le\frac1{\Gamma(n/2+1)}\int_0^n t^{n/2}e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t\le1}\tag7
$$
Apply the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

The bound in $(6)$ is pretty close as $n\to\infty$:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

$$\dfrac{1}{\Gamma(n/2+1)} \int_{0}^n t^{n/2} e^{-t}\; dt = \mathbb P(X \le n)$$ where the random variable $X$ has a Gamma distribution with scale parameter $1$ and shape parameter $n/2+1$. This distribution has mean $n/2+1$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{n/2+1}$, so $n$ is approximately $\sqrt{n/2}$ standard deviations above the mean.
By Chebyshev's inequality, the probability goes to $1$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Yes, but do you have something **less** elegant?

Comment: @ClementC. What's the point of your question?

Comment: It was a comment made in jest to show appreciation of the elegance of the answer, @user3750444

Answer (score 2):

In terms of the normalised lower incomplete gamma function $P(a,z)$,
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{1}{\Gamma(n/2+1)}\int_0^n {t^{n/2} \mathrm{e}^{ - t} \mathrm{d}t}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } P\!\left( {\tfrac{n}{2} + 1,n} \right) \le \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } (1 - \mathrm{e}^{ - n} )^{\frac{n}{2} + 1}  = 1,
$$
where I used http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.10.E11.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int t^{\frac n2}\,e^{-t}\,dt=-\Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}+1,t\right)$$
$$\int_0^n t^{\frac n2}\,e^{-t}\,dt=\Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}+1,0\right)-\Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}+1,n\right)=\Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)-\Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}+1,n\right)$$
$$\frac 1 {\Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}\int_0^n t^{\frac n2}\,e^{-t}\,dt=1-\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}+1,n\right) } { \Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}$$ The last term decreases very fast (have a look at *dlmf* for the asymptotics).