# How to prove Stirling's formula. Using Wallis formula

Tags: limits, factorial, infinity, infinite-product

[Wallis formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals) is
$$\prod ^{\infty }_{n=1}\dfrac{\left( 2n\right) ^{2}}{\left( 2n-1\right) \left( 2n+1\right) }=\dfrac{\pi }{2}$$

$$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac{2^{2n}e^{-n}n^{n}n!}{\left( 2n\right) !} \tag{1}$$
I want to prove [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)$(\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac{n!}{\sqrt{n}}\left( \dfrac{e}{n}\right) ^{n}=\sqrt{2\pi } )$ using **Wallis formula** and $(1)$.

I know method not using $(1)$ but when I use $(1)$, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You use Wallis to prove the constant in Stirling is $\sqrt{2\pi}$. To prove it, write the finite version of your first product in terms of factorials, and apply Stirling with an unknown constant.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Since $\prod\limits_{n=1}^m\frac{(2n)^2}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}=\frac{16^m}{(2m+1)\binom{2m}{m}^2}$, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3624379) might prove useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$c=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{\sqrt{2}n^{n+1/2}e^{-n}}$$

Rewrite Wallis formula as the following:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{4n}(n!)^4}{((2n)!)^2(2n+1)}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
Note that
$$\frac{2^{4n}(n!)^4}{((2n)!)^2(2n+1)}\sim\frac{2^{4n}(c\sqrt{2}n^{n+1/2}e^{-n})^4}{(c\sqrt{2}(2n)^{2n+1/2}e^{-2n})^2(2n+1)}$$
Take the limit on both sides of the relation, and apply L'Hospital,
$$\frac{\pi}{2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{n(2n+1)}=\frac{c^2}{2}$$
which gives $c=\sqrt{\pi}$.

My notation is a little bit different from you, but the general method should work.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can.