# What sequence is this $\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{2i}{2i + 1} = $?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to find a closed form solution for $\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{2i}{2i + 1} $, but I'm confused what kind of sequence this is. Does it have a closed form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify it.
\begin{align*}
\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{2i}{2i + 1} &=\frac{2^n n!}{3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n+1)}\\
&=\frac{2^{2n} (n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}
\end{align*}

Comment: How would you take the limit of this as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: When I think about it, isn't it kind of obvious that the denominator grows faster than the numerator?

Comment: HINT: Use Stirling's Formula to find the limit. Here is a sketch of this idea.
$\frac{2^{2n} (n!)^2}{(2n+1)!} \approx \frac{2^{2n} 2\pi n \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{2n}}{\sqrt{2\pi(2n+1)} \left(\frac{2n+1}{e}\right)^{2n+1}}  \approx \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{e}{\sqrt{2n+1}}\left(\frac{2n}{2n+1}\right)^{2n+1}$

Answer (score 4):

**Closed Form**
$$
\begin{align}
a_n
&=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{\color{#C00}{2k}}{\color{#090}{2k+1}}\tag{1a}\\
&=\frac{\color{#C00}{2^nn!}\,\color{#090}{2^nn!}}{\color{#090}{(2n+1)!}}\tag{1b}\\[3pt]
&=\frac{4^n}{(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}\tag{1c}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Bounds**
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{n+1}\ a_n}{\sqrt{n}\ a_{n-1}}
&=\sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n}}\frac{2n}{2n+1}\tag{2a}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{4n^3+4n^2}{4n^3+4n^2+n}}\tag{2b}\\[9pt]
&\le1\tag{2c}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, $\sqrt{n+1}\ a_n$ is decreasing.
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{n+\frac34}\ a_n}{\sqrt{n-\frac14}\ a_{n-1}}
&=\sqrt{\frac{4n+3}{4n-1}}\frac{2n}{2n+1}\tag{3a}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{16n^3+12n^2}{16n^3+12n^2-1}}\tag{3b}\\[12pt]
&\ge1\tag{3c}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, $\sqrt{n+\frac34}\ a_n$ is increasing.

Since $\sqrt{n+1}\ a_n$ is decreasing and greater than $\sqrt{n+\frac34}\ a_n$, which is increasing, and their ratio tends to $1$, they tend to a common limit, $L$.
$$
\begin{align}
L
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n+1}\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2k}{2k+1}\tag{4a}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{2n+1}\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}\tag{4b}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\tag{4c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(4a)}$: definition of $L$
$\text{(4b)}$: apply $(1)$
$\text{(4c)}$: Theorem $1$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3268210)

Thus $(2)$, $(3)$, and $(4)$ yield
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4n+4}}\le\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2k}{2k+1}\le\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4n+3}}}\tag5
$$

Comment: I use to say that beauty is part of mathematics and *vice-versa*. Once more, this is a proof that I can be right (sometimes). Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

After @Lemoine's answer, you can also write
$$P_n=\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{2i}{2i + 1}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\,\, \Gamma (n+1)}{2\,\, \Gamma \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}$$ Take logarithms, use Stirling approximation twice and continue with Taylor series to obtain
$$\log(P_n)=-\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{4 n}{\pi }\right)-\frac{3}{8 n}+\frac{1}{8 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right) $$
$$P_n=e^{\log(P_n)}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2 \sqrt{n}}\,\,\exp\Big[-\frac{3}{8 n}+\frac{1}{8 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right) \Big]$$

Try it for $n=10$; the exact value is
$$P_{10}=\frac{262144}{969969}\sim 0.270260$$ while the above truncated expansion gives $0.270272$.

Comment: It may be simpler to use one of the known asymptotic expansions for the ratio of two gamma functions: http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11.iii.

Comment: (+1) I used the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula to get the same expansion $$\log(P_n)\sim\frac12\log\left(\frac\pi{4n}\right)-\frac3{8n}+\frac1{8n^2}-\frac3{64n^3}+\frac1{64n^4}-\frac3{640n^5}+\frac1{384n^6}$$ Note that this shows that the upper bound given in my answer is tight (that is, we can't use a constant greater than $3$).