# Alternating sum of logarithms

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, logarithms, laurent-series

I'm trying to solve the product $\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{2k}{2k+1}$: 
I've started by letting it be equal to P: 
P = $\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{2k}{2k+1}$ $\implies$ ln(P) = $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \ln(\frac{2k}{2k+1})$ 
So I'm interested in the above sum of logarithms. Having manipulated the summand a little: 
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \ln(\frac{2k}{2k+1})$ = $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (\ln(2k) - \ln(2k+1))$ 
 
Expanding the sum out: 
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (\ln(2k) - \ln(2k+1))$ = ln(2) - ln(3) + ln(4) - ln(5) + ln(6) ... = $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} (-1)^k \ln(k)$ 
And this is where I'm stuck. I've attempted substituting the integral definition of the logarithm like so: 
$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} (-1)^k \ln(k)$ = $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \int_{1}^{k} \frac{1}{t}\ dt$ 
This hasn't led me anywhere. What should I do to solve this sum? I suspect a Laurent Series, but I haven't studied them enough to really know how to even begin implementing one to solve the problem.

Comment: For any $n$ you have $$\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2k}{2k-1} = \prod_{k=1}^n \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2k-1} \right) > \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k-1}.$$

Comment: Apologies, I made a mistake in typing this question up, and the denominator should've been 2k+1, as opposed to 2k-1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross multiplication shows that
$$
\left(\frac{2k}{2k+1}\right)^2\le\frac{k}{k+1}\tag1
$$
Thus
$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{2k}{2k+1}\right)^2
&\le\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{k+1}\tag{2a}\\
&=\frac1{n+1}\tag{2b}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2k}{2k+1}\le\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}\tag3
$$

Comment: Really? It shows that the product diverges to $0$ (and the sum of the logarithms diverges to $-\infty$).

Comment: As Martin R points out, this question is a duplicate.  The answers there also show that the product diverges to $0$. I see that I've also answered a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4048487).