# Identity for central binomial coefficients

Tags: reference-request, binomial-coefficients

On Wikipedia I came across the following equation for the central binomial coefficients:
$$
\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\left(1-\frac{c_n}{n}\right)
$$
for some $1/9<c_n<1/8$.

Does anyone know of a better reference for this fact than wikipedia or planet math? Also, does the equality continue to hold for positive real numbers $x$ instead of the integer $n$ if we replace the factorials involved in the definition of the binomial coefficient by Gamma functions?

Comment: The answers in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58560/elementary-central-binomial-coefficient-estimates) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be true for $x > .8305123339$ approximately: $c_x \to 0$ as $x \to 0+$.

Comment: Thanks. I'm mostly interested in $x>1$. Would you know of any reference relating to your statement?

Comment: I plotted $f(x) = x \left( 1-{{2\,x}\choose x}\sqrt {\pi \,x}{4}^{-x} \right)$, and solved $f(x) = 1/9$ numerically.

Answer (score 0):

One can find a number of estimates of the central binomial coefficient in the following papers and closely-related references therein.

@article {MR4127765,
AUTHOR = {Popov, A. Yu.},
TITLE = {Two-sided estimates of the central binomial coefficient},
JOURNAL = {Chelyab. Fiz.-Mat. Zh.},
FJOURNAL = {Chelyabinski\u{\i} Fiziko-Matematicheski\u{\i} Zhurnal},
VOLUME = {5},
YEAR = {2020},
NUMBER = {1},
PAGES = {56-69},
ISSN = {2500-0101},
MRCLASS = {05A10 (05A15)},
MRNUMBER = {4127765},
DOI = {10.24411/2500-0101-2020-15105},
URL = {https://doi.org/10.24411/2500-0101-2020-15105},
}

@article {MR4127766,
AUTHOR = {Tikhonov, I. V. and Sherstyukov, V. B. and Tsvetkovich, D. G.},
TITLE = {Comparative analysis of two-sided estimates of the central
binomial coefficient},
JOURNAL = {Chelyab. Fiz.-Mat. Zh.},
FJOURNAL = {Chelyabinski\u{\i} Fiziko-Matematicheski\u{\i} Zhurnal},
VOLUME = {5},
YEAR = {2020},
NUMBER = {1},
PAGES = {70-95},
ISSN = {2500-0101},
MRCLASS = {05A10 (33B15 40A15)},
MRNUMBER = {4127766},
DOI = {10.24411/2500-0101-2020-15106},
URL = {https://doi.org/10.24411/2500-0101-2020-15106},
}

@article {MR1702663,
AUTHOR = {Sasv'{a}ri, Zolt'{a}n},
TITLE = {Inequalities for binomial coefficients},
JOURNAL = {J. Math. Anal. Appl.},
FJOURNAL = {Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications},
VOLUME = {236},
YEAR = {1999},
NUMBER = {1},
PAGES = {223--226},
ISSN = {0022-247X},
MRCLASS = {26D15 (05A10)},
MRNUMBER = {1702663},
DOI = {10.1006/jmaa.1999.6420},
URL = {https://doi.org/10.1006/jmaa.1999.6420},
}

Answer (score 0):

Let
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{Z}&=\{0,\pm1,\pm2,\dotsc\}, & \mathbb{N}&=\{1,2,\dotsc\},\\
\mathbb{N}_0&=\{0,1,2,\dotsc\}, & \mathbb{N}_-&=\{-1,-2,\dotsc\}.
\end{align*}
The extended binomial coefficient $\binom{z}{w}$ for $z,w\in\mathbb{C}$ is defined by
\begin{equation}\label{Gen-Coeff-Binom}
\binom{z}{w}=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\Gamma(z+1)}{\Gamma(w+1)\Gamma(z-w+1)}, & z\not\in\mathbb{N}_-,\quad w,z-w\not\in\mathbb{N}_-;\\
0, & z\not\in\mathbb{N}_-,\quad w\in\mathbb{N}_- \text{ or } z-w\in\mathbb{N}_-;\\
\dfrac{\langle z\rangle_w}{w!},& z\in\mathbb{N}_-, \quad w\in\mathbb{N}_0;\\
\dfrac{\langle z\rangle_{z-w}}{(z-w)!}, & z,w\in\mathbb{N}_-, \quad z-w\in\mathbb{N}_0;\\
0, & z,w\in\mathbb{N}_-, \quad z-w\in\mathbb{N}_-;\\
\infty, & z\in\mathbb{N}_-, \quad w\not\in\mathbb{Z},
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation*}%\label{falling-Factorial}
\langle\alpha\rangle_n=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(\alpha-k)
=
\begin{cases}
\alpha(\alpha-1)\dotsm(\alpha-n+1), & n\in\mathbb{N}\\
1, & n=0
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
is called the falling factorial.

Equation (10) on page 116 in the paper [1] below reads that the double inequality
\begin{equation}\label{Merkle-gamma-ineq}\tag{1}
6^x<\frac{\Gamma(2(1+x))}{\Gamma^2(1+x)}<(1+x)3^x
\end{equation}
holds for $x\in(0,1)$ and its reversed inequality is valid for $x>1$. We can reformulate the double inequality \eqref{Merkle-gamma-ineq} as follows: the double inequality
\begin{equation}\label{Gen-Central-Binom-Coeff-bounds-Eq}\tag{2}
\frac{6^x}{2x+1}>\binom{2x}{x}>\frac{(x+1)3^x}{2x+1}
\end{equation}
is valid for $x>1$ and its reversed version holds for $0<x<1$.

By the way, I have verified the following double inequalities:

- For $(0,+\infty)$, the double inequality
  \begin{equation}\label{centr-binom-(2x+1)ineq}\tag{3}
  \frac{2^{2x}}{2x+1}<\binom{2x}{x}<\frac{e^{2x}}{2x+1}
  \end{equation}
  is sharp in the sense that the bases $2$ and $e$ cannot be replaced by larger and smaller constants, respectively.
  For $x\in\bigl(-\frac{1}{2},0\bigr)$, the right hand side inequality in \eqref{centr-binom-(2x+1)ineq} is still valid, but the left hand side inequality in \eqref{centr-binom-(2x+1)ineq} is reversed.
- For $x\in(0,+\infty)$, the double inequality
  \begin{equation}\label{binom(2x+1)(x)-ineq}\tag{4}
  e^x<\binom{2x+1}{x}<4^x
  \end{equation}
  is sharp in the sense that the bases $e$ and $4$ cannot be replaced by larger and smaller constants, respectively.
  For $x\in\bigl(-\frac{3}{2},0\bigr)$, the left hand side inequality in \eqref{binom(2x+1)(x)-ineq} is still valid, but the right hand side inequality in \eqref{binom(2x+1)(x)-ineq} is reversed.

I am looking for a suitable outlet for publishing, among other closely related things, the double inequalities \eqref{centr-binom-(2x+1)ineq} and \eqref{binom(2x+1)(x)-ineq}.

References

1. Milan Merkle, *On log-convexity of a ratio of gamma functions*, Univ. Beograd. Publ. Elektrotehn. Fak. Ser. Mat. **8** (1997), 114--119; available online at https://www.jstor.org/stable/43666390.
2. Feng Qi, Chao-Ping Chen, and Dongkyu Lim, *Several identities containing central binomial coefficients and derived from series expansions of powers of the arcsine function*, Results in Nonlinear Analysis **4** (2021), no. 1, 57--64; available online at https://doi.org/10.53006/rna.867047.
3. Yue-Wu Li and Feng Qi, *The sum of an alternating series involving central binomial numbers and its three proofs*, Journal of the Korea Society of Mathematical Education Series B: The Pure and Applied Mathematics **28** (2021), no. 4, in press.