# Approximation of factorial - Stirling formula

Tags: binomial-coefficients, approximation, factorial

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Elementary central binomial coefficient estimates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58560/elementary-central-binomial-coefficient-estimates)

How can I prove that
$$
 \binom{n}{n/2} = \Theta\left(\frac{2^n}{\sqrt n}\right)
$$

I tried with Stirlings approximation formula, but still don't find a way of doing it correctly :(

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Useful keywords ['central binomial coefficient'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient) for $n$ even.

Comment: Well, Stirling's formula *is* one fairly straightforward way of doing it. So what did you do, and what went wrong?