# How can we prove the Inequality : $ \frac {n!}{ 2^{n-1}((\frac {n-1}{2})!)^2} \leq \sqrt{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

How can we prove the following inequality? For every odd positive integer $n$,

$$ \frac {n!}{ 2^{n-1}((\frac {n-1}{2})!)^2} \leq \sqrt{n}$$

Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried applying some form of Stirling's formula, to see what comes out?

Comment: is it for $n$ odd (else $\frac{n-1}{2}$ isn't an integer) (i hope odd is the right one)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that $n$ is odd

Comment: @GerryMyerson Something similar to Stirling would surely help, but we cannot apply Stirling right ahead since that is an asymptotic inequality.

Comment: @AD [Non asymptotic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) versions exist.

Comment: @Did SURE, but it is not the classical Stirling. Agreed?

Comment: @AD (No caps please.) Thus the assertion that one cannot use Stirling "because Stirling is only asymptotic" needs, at least, some qualification. Note that the ratio between the lower and the upper nonasymptotic bounds valid for every $n\geqslant1$ is only 2.5:2.8.

Comment: @Did (Sorry, I did not mean to yell.. I did not think about the capitals). Yes, but that needs *some* job and not just a direct application. Some authors present exact inequalities without any proof or reference and I think that builds a bad community, if you see what I mean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my answer [here,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58560/elementary-central-binomial-coefficient-estimates/58562#58562) I show that 
$${2n\choose n}{1\over 4^n}\leq {1\over\sqrt{\pi n}}.$$

Substitute $(n-1)/2$ for $n$ to get
$${n-1\choose (n-1)/2}{1\over 2^{n-1}}\leq {1\over\sqrt{\pi (n-1)/2}}\leq{1\over\sqrt{n}},$$
the final inequality being valid for  $n\geq 3$, since $\pi (n-1)/2>n$ for such $n$.

Comment: Well, this is impressive, +1.

Comment: I love central binomial coefficients!

Comment: +1 Nice! :)  Perhaps you have some idea of using a binomial expansion and some orthogonality method in order to pick the mid term?

Comment: @AD. Sorry, I don't have any ideas along those lines.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland No problem at all.....

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:*

For $k\geq0$ we need to show $$a_k=\frac{(2k+1)!}{2^{2k}(k!)^2}\leq\sqrt{2k+1}=b_k$$

Now $$a_{k+1}=\frac{(2k+3)!}{2^{2k+2}((k+1)!)^2}= \frac{(2k+3)(2k+2)}{4(k+1)^2}\cdot \frac{(2k+1)!}{2^{2k}(k!)^2}=\frac{(2k+3)(2k+2)}{4(k+1)^2}\cdot a_k$$
So if we knew $a_k\leq b_k$ for some $k$ then could we perhaps continue with induction...?

---

A nicer proof might be hidden in the in the binomial formula - something like
$$ 2^{2k} = (1+1)^{2k} =\sum_{j=0}^{2k} \frac{(2k)!}{j! (2k-j)!}$$ 
where the mid term is of interest...

Answer (score 1):

As Gerry Mentioned, Stirling formula will show it (as this is only an asymptotic behaviour we first needs a lower bound for which we know the equation is true). If you don't want to use such a hammer, you  should try it with induction.

Comment: We can not use Stirling for specific $n$ without further investigation, it is an asymptotic inequality.

Comment: @Ad. did you downvote? tell me if you don't like the edit

Comment: @AD [Non asymptotic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) versions exist.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis I give you +1 for the second comment (*thus proving I did not downvote you*)..

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here is the proof by induction:

*Base Case:*  The case $ n = 1$ is easy to check.

*Inductive Step:*  Assume that $$\frac{k!}{2^{k-1} \left( \frac{k-1}{2} \right)!^2} \leq \sqrt{k}.$$  We aim to show that this implies $$\frac{(k+2)!}{2^{k+1} \left( \frac{k+1}{2} \right)!^2} \leq \sqrt{k+2}.$$

We have

\begin{align}
\frac{(k+2)!}{2^{k+1} \left( \frac{k+1}{2} \right)!^2} &= \frac{(k+2)(k+1)}{4(\frac{k+1}{2})^2} \cdot \frac{k!}{2^{k-1} \left( \frac{k-1}{2} \right)!^2}
\\
&\leq \frac{(k+2)(k+1)}{4(\frac{k+1}{2})^2} \cdot \sqrt{k}
\\
&= \frac{k+2}{k+1} \sqrt{k}
\\
&\leq \sqrt{k+2}
\end{align}
which occurs if and only if $\left( \frac{k+2}{k+1}\right)^2 k \leq k+2$.  I will leave the last inequality for you to check.

Comment: after your hint I had done this induction proof.
Thank You so much.

Comment: I'm happy to help!