# Olympiad inequality with odd and even numbers up to 10000

Tags: inequality, contest-math

To prove:
$$\frac{1\cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot ... \cdot 9999}{2\cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdot ... \cdot 10000} < \frac{1}{100} $$

I've got to the point that the left side of the equation above is equal to $$\frac{10000!}{2^{10000} \cdot (5000!)^2}$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove the inequality $\frac{1}{1999}<\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdots1997}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot8\cdots1998}<\frac{1}{44}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814005/prove-the-inequality-frac11999-frac1-cdot3-cdot5-cdot7-cdots19972-cdot)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mathematical induction problem: $\frac12\cdot \frac34\cdots\frac{2n-1}{2n}<\frac1{\sqrt{2n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1899857/mathematical-induction-problem-frac12-cdot-frac34-cdots-frac2n-12n-frac?noredirect=1&lq=1)