# Evaluating $\sum^{n-1}_{j=0} \binom{n}{j}\binom{n}{j+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Is there a simpler expression for the following sum? $(n\in\mathbb{N})$
$$S_n =\binom{n}{0}\binom{n}{1} + \binom{n}{1}\binom{n}{2} + \dots + \binom{n}{n-1}\binom{n}{n}$$
It seems like $S_n = \binom{2n}{n-1}$, however I have no clue as to how I can prove that relation. I also tried re-writing the sum as
$$S_n = \binom{n}{0}\binom{n}{n-1} + \binom{n}{1}\binom{n}{n-2} + \dots + \binom{n}{n-1}\binom{n}{0} = \sum^{n-1}_{j=0}\binom{n}{j}\binom{n}{n-j-1}$$
Which *resembles* a special case of [Vandemonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity). Is there a connection between the two?

Comment: See also [Find a simple formula for $\binom{n}{0}\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{1}\binom{n}{2}+...+\binom{n}{n-1}\binom{n}{n}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/351363). Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum%5E%7Bn-1%7D_%7Bj%3D0%7D%20%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7Bj%7D%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7Bj%2B1%7D%24&p=1).