# Lower bound for expectation of absolute sum of Rademacher

Tags: probability, expectation, random-walk

Let $\epsilon_i$ be i.i.d. Rademacher random variables (i.e., $\epsilon_i$ takes value $\pm 1$ with equal probability). The upper bound $\mathbb{E} |\sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i| \le \sqrt{n}$ follows from Jensen's inequality. [Can this be sharpened easily?]

My main question: is there a simple lower bound for this expectation?

Comment: One knows that $E|\epsilon_1+\cdots+\epsilon_n|/\sqrt{n}\to E|Z|$ where $Z$ is standard normal hence $E|Z|=\sqrt{2/\pi}$.

Comment: My answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/883982/non-probabilistic-argument-for-divergence-of-the-simple-random-walk/884211#884211  gives an explicit formula for $\mathbb{E}\left|\sum_{i=1}^{2n} \epsilon_i\right|$. You can get upper and lower bounds if you follow the links there.

Comment: @Did Thanks, that is a good sanity check that I forgot. Do you know of any non-asymptotic bounds? I am hoping for a lower bound of the form $\ge c \sqrt{n}$.

Comment: ?? Did you check @Byron's link?

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Ah thanks! So for even $n$, we have $\ge \sqrt{n/2}$?

Comment: @angryavian Yes, that is what I get. I moved my comment to an answer.

Comment: See https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Khintchine_inequality

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[My answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/883982/non-probabilistic-argument-for-divergence-of-the-simple-random-walk/884211#884211)   gives an explicit formula for $\mathbb{E}\left|\sum_{i=1}^{2n} \epsilon_i\right|$. 
You can get the lower bound 
$$\mathbb{E}\left|\sum_{i=1}^{2n} \epsilon_i\right|\geq \sqrt{n}, \tag1$$
if you combine (1) with the bound at [the link there.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58560/elementary-central-binomial-coefficient-estimates/58562#58562)

Comment: Do you know what happens in the odd case?

Comment: The value for $2m-1$ is the same as the value for $2m$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Why is that?

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^{2m-1} \epsilon_i$ is odd.  Adding $\epsilon_{2m}$ will either increase the absolute value by $1$ or decrease it by $1$, with equal probabilities, so it doesn't change the expectation.