# Combinatorial identity / expected distance of random walk

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I am struggling to verify the following identity.

> $$\binom{2m}{m} \frac{m}{2} = \sum_{j=1}^m j \binom{2m}{m+j}$$

I've tried induction, but I run into issues inside the sum. I can't see a combinatorial interpretation either. I've noted the right-hand side can be rewritten as $\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=-m}^m |j| \binom{2m}{m+j}$, but this seems more complicated. Any hints would be appreciated!

Aside: my goal is actually to compute the equality in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/883982/non-probabilistic-argument-for-divergence-of-the-simple-random-walk/884211#884211) (expected distance of a one-dimensional random walk). Is there a more direct way to verify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} \binom{2m}{j} & = \sum_{j=m+1}^{2m} \binom{2m}{j} = \frac{1}{2} \left( 2^{2m} - \binom{2m}{m} \right) \\
%
\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} \binom{2m-1}{j} & = \sum_{j=m}^{2m-1} \binom{2m-1}{j} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2^{2m-1}.
\end{align*}

Then

\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^m j \binom{2m}{m+j} & = \sum_{j=1}^m (m+j) \binom{2m}{m+j}  - \sum_{j=1}^m m \binom{2m}{m+j} \\
%
& = 2m \sum_{j=0}^{m-1} \binom{2m-1}{m+j} - m \left( 2^{2m} - \binom{2m}{m} \right) \cdot \frac{1}{2} \\
%
& = 2m \cdot 2^{2m-1}\cdot \frac{1}{2}   - m \cdot 2^{2m-1}+ \frac{m}{2} \binom{2m}{m}  \\
%
& = \frac{m}{2}\binom{2m}{m}.
%
\end{align*}