# Prove that $\sum ( \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{2i-1}{2i} )^3$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

It is asked to prove that the series
$$\sum_n (\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{2i-1}{2i})^3$$

converges.

Unfortunately, the ratio test is not conclusive, so I am trying to apply the comparasion test. I've noted that

$$\prod (\frac{2i-1}{2i})^3 = (1/2^3)^n \prod (\frac{2i-1}{i})^3$$

Which not helps, since 2i -1 > i

I would be glad if someone could leave some suggestion.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you prove that $\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{2i-1}{2i}=\theta\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$ by considering logarithms, for instance?

Comment: I've tried to apply the log on the produtory but couldnt find it.

Comment: $\log\left(1-\frac{1}{2i}\right) = -\frac{1}{2i}+O\left(\frac{1}{i^2}\right).$ By summing over $i$, then exponentiating back, you get that the product behaves like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, hence the series is convergent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58560/elementary-central-binomial-coefficient-estimates/58562#58562) I show that 
$$ \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{2i-1}{2i}\leq {3\over 4\sqrt{n+1}},$$
which gets you what you want.