# Combinatorics in chess

Tags: combinatorics

Let $
ABCD
\
$ be an finite chessboard ($n*n$ tiles) where $A$ is the left lower corner and $C$ its opposite.
Each tile is denoted by a square with length $L=1$.

Our purpose is to determine the number of possible roads  (denoted by $x_n$)  from $A$ to $C$ knowing that we can ONLY travel from from a vertex to another through horizontal (strictly rightwards) and vertically upward lines.

Hint: for large enough $n$ the number of paths $x_n$ contains the number $
\sqrt {2\pi } 
$ and some power of $2$....

It's my first time seeing this kind of problem and I'd really appreciate if someone could shed some insight or maybe provide a solution..

Comment: Are you also restricted to only moving rightwards/upwards? Otherwise you don't have a finite number of ways to move between tiles.

Comment: This is the exact text, but I think you're right, so we should consider the horizontal paths oriented rightwards

Comment: We will be taking a sequence of $2n$ consecutive steps, $n$ rightward and $n$ upward. We can **choose** which $n$ steps in the sequence are rightward in $\binom{2n}{n}$ ways. The same idea works for an $m\times n$ board.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A legal  path can be completely described by a word of length $2n$ made up of $n$ occurrences of the letter R (right) and $n$ occurrences of the letter U (up). Every path determines a unique word, and every word determines a unique path.

There are $\binom{2n}{n}$ such words. For there are $\binom{2n}{n}$ ways to **choose** the $n$ places  in the word where R's occur.

**Remark:** The $\sqrt{2\pi}$ stuff in the hint refers to the [Stirling approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) to the factorial.

The same idea can be used with a $m\times n$ board. In that case there are $\binom{m+n}{m}$ "up and/or right" paths from the bottom left corner to the top right.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your beautiful explanation .I asked my teacher for the correct answer and I got $
2^{2n + 1} \sqrt {2\pi } $ . I really don't get the sqrt(2pi) bit..

Comment: The number $\binom{2n}{n}$ is $\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}$. By the Sirling approximation (please see Wikipedia) and some manipulation we find that $\binom{2n}{n}\approx \frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$. The approximation to $\binom{2n}{n}$ that you quote is not correct.

Comment: out of curiosity, what would be the error of this approximation ?

Comment: Which approximation, Stirling or the wrong one? The article I linked to has information about the error in the Stirling approximation, and the error in the central binomial coefficient would be smaller. From the point of view of **ratio** the Stirling approximation is quickly very good.

Comment: The Stirling one in this particular case

Comment: There are many discussions of this, at various levels. For a fairly simple error estimate, please see the answers to [this MSE question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58560/elementary-central-binomial-coefficient-estimates)