# Computing $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{4^{n}}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \binom{2n-1}{n-k}\frac{ 1}{(2k-1)^2+\pi^2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, limits

What tools would you recommend me for computing the limit below?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{4^{n}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\displaystyle \binom{2n-1}{n-k}}{(2k-1)^2+\pi^2}$$

As soon as any useful idea comes to mind I'll make the proper update with the new findings.

Comment: your sum leads to a hypergeometric series

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After I posted my earlier answer, I realized that this can be handled in a much simpler way.

Pick an $\epsilon\gt0$.

---

**Most of the series is contained in a finite sum**

This identity is proven in [my earlier answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1017366):
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{(2k-1)^2+\pi^2}=\frac14\tanh(\pi^2/2)\tag{1}
$$
Since the series in $(1)$ converges, we know that there is a $K$ so that
$$
0\le\sum_{k=K+1}^\infty\frac1{(2k-1)^2+\pi^2}=\frac14\tanh(\pi^2/2)-\sum_{k=1}^K\frac1{(2k-1)^2+\pi^2}\le\epsilon\tag{2}
$$

---

**Where most of the series is contained, the coefficients are almost equal**

Now, using $(10)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/932509), we have
$$
\frac{\sqrt{n}}{4^n}\binom{2n-1}{n}=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{4^n}\frac12\binom{2n}{n}\sim\frac{\sqrt{n}}{4^n}\frac12\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}=\frac1{2\sqrt{\pi}}\tag{3}
$$
Therefore, there is an $M$ so that for $n\ge M$,
$$
\frac1{2\sqrt{\pi}}(1-\epsilon)\le\frac{\sqrt{n}}{4^n}\binom{2n-1}{n}\le\frac1{2\sqrt{\pi}}(1+\epsilon)\tag{4}
$$

Consider that
$$
\binom{2n-1}{n-k}=\binom{2n-1}{n}\frac{n-1}{n+1}\frac{n-2}{n+2}\cdots\frac{n-k+1}{n+k-1}\tag{5}
$$
Since we can choose an $N$ so that for all $n\ge N$ and $k\le K$,
$$
1-\epsilon\le\frac{n-1}{n+1}\frac{n-2}{n+2}\cdots\frac{n-k+1}{n+k-1}\le1\tag{6}
$$
we can combine $(4)$, $(5)$, and $(6)$ to get that for all $n\ge\max(M,N)$ and $k\le K$,
$$
\frac1{2\sqrt{\pi}}(1-\epsilon)^2\le\frac{\sqrt{n}}{4^n}\binom{2n-1}{n-k}\le\frac1{2\sqrt{\pi}}(1+\epsilon)\tag{7}
$$

---

**The coefficients are bounded everywhere**

Notice that $(4)$ and $(5)$ also tell us that for all $n\ge M$,
$$
\frac{\sqrt{n}}{4^n}\binom{2n-1}{n-k}\le\frac1{2\sqrt{\pi}}(1+\epsilon)\tag{8}
$$

---

**Put it all together**

For $n\ge M$, we have from $(2)$ and $(8)$,
$$
\frac{\sqrt{n}}{4^n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\binom{2n-1}{n-k}}{(2k-1)^2+\pi^2}
\le\frac14\tanh(\pi^2/2)\frac1{2\sqrt{\pi}}(1+\epsilon)\tag{9}
$$
For $n\ge\max(M,N)$, we have from $(2)$ and $(7)$,
$$
\frac{\sqrt{n}}{4^n}\sum_{k=1}^K\frac{\binom{2n-1}{n-k}}{(2k-1)^2+\pi^2}
\ge\left(\frac14\tanh(\pi^2/2)-\epsilon\right)\frac1{2\sqrt{\pi}}(1-\epsilon)^2\tag{10}
$$
Since $\epsilon\gt0$ was arbitrary, we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{4^n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\binom{2n-1}{n-k}}{(2k-1)^2+\pi^2}=\frac1{8\sqrt\pi}\tanh(\pi^2/2)\tag{11}
$$

Comment: Nice work. Not sure why I didn't leave any comment at this answer. :)

Answer (score 12):

Since:
$$\frac{1}{(2k-1)^2+\pi^2}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi}e^{-(2k-1)x}\,dx $$
and:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n-1}{n-k}e^{-(2k-1)x}=\binom{2n-1}{n-1}\cdot\sum_{h=0}^{+\infty}\left(e^{-(2h+1)x}\prod_{k=0}^{h}\frac{n-k}{n+k}\right),$$
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{4^n}\binom{2n-1}{n-1}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}},$$
the value of the limit is given by:
$$L=\frac{1}{2\pi^{3/2}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sum_{h=0}^{+\infty}\left(e^{-(2h+1)x}\sin(\pi x)\prod_{k=0}^{h}\frac{n-k}{n+k}\right)dx.$$
As long as $n\to +\infty$, the products appearing in the previous line get closer and closer to $1$.

By the dominated convergence theorem,

> $$ L = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{h=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(2h+1)^2+\pi^2}=\frac{1}{8\sqrt{\pi}}\tanh\frac{\pi^2}{2},$$

where the last identity follows by considering the logarithmic derivatives of the Weierstrass product for the $\cosh$ function.

Comment: Interesting approach (+1)

Comment: (+1) Neat answer. I used a couple of different ideas, so I don't think my answer looks too close to this.

Answer (score 7):

This answer matches up with Jack D'Aurizio's at $(3)$, but I thought it was distinct enough not to delete it.

---

The second derivative of $\log\binom{2n-1}{n-k}$ between $k=0$ and $k=1$ is $-\frac2n$. This means that a good approximation for $\binom{2n-1}{n-k}$ is $\frac{2^{2n-1}}{\sqrt{\pi n}}e^{-(k-\frac12)^2/n}$. For example at $n=100$,

$\hspace{3.4cm}$[image]

Since equation $(9)$ in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/143179) is valid for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$, we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2+z^2}=\frac1{2z}\left[\pi\coth(\pi z)-\frac1z\right]\tag{1}
$$
Thus, we can compute
$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{4^n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\binom{2n-1}{n-k}}{(2k-1)^2+\pi^2}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{4^n}\frac{2^{2n-1}}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{e^{-(k-\frac12)^2/n}}{(2k-1)^2+\pi^2}\tag{2}\\
&=\frac1{2\sqrt\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{(2k-1)^2+\pi^2}\tag{3}\\
&=\frac1{2\sqrt\pi}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2+\pi^2}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{4k^2+\pi^2}\right)\tag{4}\\
&=\frac1{2\sqrt\pi}\left(\color{#C00000}{\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2+\pi^2}}\color{#00A000}{-\frac14\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2+\pi^2/4}}\right)\tag{5}\\
&=\frac1{2\sqrt\pi}\left(\color{#C00000}{\frac12\coth(\pi^2)-\frac1{2\pi^2}}\color{#00A000}{-\frac14\coth(\pi^2/2)+\frac1{2\pi^2}}\right)\tag{6}\\
&=\frac1{8\sqrt\pi}\tanh(\pi^2/2)\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(2)$: approximate the binomial by the appropriate normal distribution
$(3)$: cancel terms and apply Dominated Convergence (or Monotone Convergence, either works)
$(4)$: the sum over the odds is the full sum minus the evens
$(5)$: prepare to apply $(1)$
$(6)$: apply $(1)$
$(7)$: cancel terms and use $2\coth(2x)-\coth(x)=\tanh(x)$

Comment: Very clever (+1)