# Good approximation for $\binom{N}{\frac{N}{2}}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, approximation

$$\log_2\binom{N}{\frac{N}{2}}\approx N\log_2N - 2(N-\frac{N}{2})\log_2(N-\frac{N}{2})=N\log_2N - 2\frac{N}{2}\log_2(\frac{N}{2})$$
$$=N\log_2N - {N}{}\log_2({N}) + {N}{}=N$$
$$\implies\binom{N}{\frac{N}{2}}\approx 2^{N}$$

Is my approximation correct?

Or the following one correct?

$$\begin{align}
\log {n\choose m} & \approx (n+\tfrac{1}{2})\log n - (m+\tfrac{1}{2})\log m - (n-m+\tfrac{1}{2})\log (n-m) - \tfrac{1}{2}\log 2\pi
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}
\log {n\choose \frac{n}{2}} & \approx (n+\tfrac{1}{2})\log n - (\frac{n}{2}+\tfrac{1}{2})\log \frac{n}{2} - (n-\frac{n}{2}+\tfrac{1}{2})\log (n-\frac{n}{2}) - \tfrac{1}{2}\log 2\pi\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}\approx(n+\tfrac{1}{2})\log n - (\frac{n}{2}+\tfrac{1}{2})\log \frac{n}{2} - (\frac{n}{2}+\tfrac{1}{2})\log (\frac{n}{2}) - \tfrac{1}{2}\log 2\pi\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}=(n+\tfrac{1}{2})\log n - (n+1)\log \frac{n}{2}=(n+\tfrac{1}{2})\log n - (n+1)\log {n} + (n+1) - \tfrac{1}{2}\log 2\pi
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}=-\tfrac{1}{2}\log n + (n+1) - \tfrac{1}{2}\log 2\pi
\end{align}$$
$$\implies{n\choose \frac{n}{2}}\approx\frac{2^{n+1}}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$$

What is a reasonable approximation?

Comment: That's much too large.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient for some asymptotics

Comment: You can't use an approximation of the log to get an approximation, because $a_n \sim b_n$ doesn't imply $e^{a_n} \sim e^{b_n}$.

Comment: Worth also looking at [Catalan Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) approximation.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58560/elementary-central-binomial-coefficient-estimates

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wikipedia gives the approximation
$$\frac{2^{n+\frac12}}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$$
This comes from Stirling's formula, and the quotient of this by the binomial coefficient approaches 1 as $n\to\infty$.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Bounds_and_asymptotic_formulas) is the article.

Comment: Always good to include a link when referencing Wikipedia.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews added. I went to the link on my computer and I'm writing the answer on my phone, which is pretty hard. Only now did I realize that I could've gone to the site on my phone and copied and pasted the link. Live and learn.