# Binomial Theorem Help

Tags: calculus, binomial-coefficients

In my assignment I have the following question:

[image: question]

Alan

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Thank you. Is it bad I'm writing it the way I did?

Comment: The problem is that it's not searchable, doesn't show up in the question preview (front page "teaser" of the body) and looks pixelated. Also it consumes more bandwidth than necessary so, yes the format is bad. However, the question itself is asked nicely, so I'm convinced you'll learn MathJax and keep posting good questions like this one ;)

Comment: Thank you! I will study the format, and I thank you for your tips!

Comment: Also note that you can inspect any Math $\mathfrak{such\ as\ this}$ with a right-click and "Show Math As $\blacktriangleright$ TeX commands". Try it out with my answer for example ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use a more straight-forward approach:
$$4^n = (1+1)^{2n} = \sum_{i=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}i 1^i 1^{2n-i} = \sum_{i=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}i$$
Now since binomial coefficients are nonnegative, we get
$$4^n \ge \binom{2n}i \qquad \forall 0\le i\le 2n$$
Especially for $i=n$.

Comment: This is definitely the way the hint suggests.

Answer (score 2):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/932509), a simple argument shows that
$$
\binom{2n}{n}\frac{\sqrt{n+\frac13}}{4^n}
$$
is decreasing. Therefore, for any $n\ge0$, we have
$$
\binom{2n}{n}\le\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{3n+1}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Alan.Here is my suggestion.
consider $(1+x)^{2n}$, then the coefficient of $x^n$ is $\binom{2n}{n}$.
we notice $(1+x)^{2n}$=$\sum_{i=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{i}x^i$,and $\binom{2n}{i}\geq 1$.
So if we let x=1, then we have $\binom{2n}{n}\leq\sum_{i=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{i}1^i=\sum_{i=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{i}$.
and when x=1,$\sum_{i=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{i}=(1+1)^{2n}=2^{2n}=4^n$.
Finally, we have $\binom{2n}{n} \leq 4^n$.