# Find the limit of $4^n\cdot\binom{2n}{n}/\binom{4n}{2n}$

Tags: limits, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to prove that $$f(n)=4^n\frac{\dbinom{2n}{n}}{\dbinom{4n}{2n}}$$ converges as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

I have already tried to use the fact that, if $n, k \in\mathbb{N}, n\geq k\geq1,$ then $(\frac{n}{k})^k\leq\binom{n}{k}\leq e^k(\frac{n}{k})^k$.  However, this has been to no avail.

Could anybody suggest how I could approach this proof?

Comment: You could use [Stirling's Approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) to estimate the central binomial coefficient.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done directly, without Stirling. Note that after the simplification of the factorials the sequence becomes
$$ f_n = \frac{2n+2}{2n+1}\frac{2n+4}{2n+3}...\frac{4n}{4n-1}  $$

Taking $\log$ we see that 
$$\log f_n = \log\left(1+\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)+...+\log\left(1+\frac{1}{4n-1}\right)$$
Using the fact that $\log (1+x) \simeq x$ for $x$ close to $0$, we have

$$ \log f_n \simeq \frac{1}{2n+1}+...+\frac{1}{4n-1}$$

Now denote $a_n = \displaystyle \frac{1}{n+1}+...+\frac{1}{2n}$. Using partial sums of a Riemann integral, or the logarithm approximation, we find that $a_n \to \ln 2$.

Now just note that $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2n+1}+...+\frac{1}{4n-1} = a_{2n}-\frac{a_n}{2}$. Therefore 
$$ \log f_n \to \frac{\ln 2}{2}$$
which implies that $f_n \to \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: (+1) 'without stirling' .. its just another application of partial summation formula on $H_n$.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Use the asymptotic properties of the [Central Binomial Coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient) to find $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)$

$$n\to\infty\implies \binom{2n}{n}\sim \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\quad\textrm{and}\quad\binom{4n}{2n}\sim\frac{4^{2n}}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}$$

The limit will come out as $\sqrt 2$ proving that the limit converges.

Comment: I suppose that you have a typo in the first approximation : the $2$ should not be present in the radical.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, It was a typo actually. Fixed it now. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: ...which is the direct consequence of using Stirling's formula

Comment: @Alex, yes, I know that. I just wrote it like that since this is also a pretty well-known result.

Answer (score 3):

Inequality $(10)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/932509) shows that
$$
\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi(n+\frac13)}}\le\binom{2n}{n}\le\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi(n+\frac14)}}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\sqrt{\frac{2n+\frac14}{n+\frac13}}\le4^n\frac{\dbinom{2n}{n}}{\dbinom{4n}{2n}}\le\sqrt{\frac{2n+\frac13}{n+\frac14}}
$$
The Squeeze Theorem says that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}4^n\frac{\dbinom{2n}{n}}{\dbinom{4n}{2n}}=\sqrt2
$$