# Getting tight asymptotic upper and lower bounds of combinatorical expression

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics

$$\binom{n}{\frac{n}2}$$

I tried to do some rough estimates, but I didn't succeed at all well. Can somebody give a clue?
Oh and i Forgot to mention, without Stirling formula.

One thought is to do fraction and get:
$$\frac{\frac{n}{2}+1}{\frac{n}{2}}\cdot \frac{\frac{n}{2}+2}{n-1}\cdot ...\cdot \frac{\frac{n}{2}+1+2\left(\frac{n}{2}-1\right)}{\frac{n}{2}-\left(\frac{n}{2}-1\right)}\:=\:\left(1+\frac{1}{\frac{n}{2}}\right)\cdot ...\cdot \left(1+2\cdot \frac{n}{2}+1\right)$$

$$\theta \left(n\right)=\frac{n}{2}\cdot \left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)\le \left(1+\frac{1}{\frac{n}{2}}\right)\cdot ...\cdot \left(1+2\cdot \frac{n}{2}+1\right)\le \frac{n}{2}\left(2+n\right)=\theta \left(n^2\right)$$

Is that correct?

Comment: Do you know Stirling formula ?

Comment: [Here](https://wimcouwenberg.wordpress.com/2014/12/28/bounds-for-central-binomial-coefficients/) is one way to obtain such bounds.

Comment: The answers to [this MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/133732/upper-limit-on-the-central-binomial-coefficient) give several upper bounds. **Byron Schmuland**’s answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58560/elementary-central-binomial-coefficient-estimates) gives upper and lower bounds.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be something differently from what I got, but why is my try wrong from the first place ?