# Asymptotic approximation of Catalan Numbers

Tags: asymptotics, catalan-numbers

The nth Catalan number is  :
$$C_n = \frac {1} {n+1} \times {2n \choose n}$$
The problem 12-4 of CLRS asks to find :
$$C_n = \frac {4^n} { \sqrt {\pi} n^{3/2}} (1+ O(1/n)) $$ 
And Stirling's approximation is:
$$n! = \sqrt {2 \pi n} {\left( \frac {n}{e} \right)}^{n} {\left( 1+ \Theta \left(\frac {1} {n}\right) \right)} $$ 
So, the nth catalan number becomes :
$$C_n = \frac {2n!}{(n+1)(n!)^2} $$
That, after applying Stirling's approximation becomes:
$$C_n = \left( \frac {1}{1+n} \right) \left( \frac {4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}} \right) \frac {1}{\left( 1+\Theta \left(1/n\right) \right)}$$
And then, it becomes hopeless. The Asymptotic bound comes in the denominator, not in the numerator.
What should be done now?

Any help appreciated.
Moon

Comment: $\frac1{1+O\left(\frac1n\right)}=1+O\!\left(\frac1n\right)$. For example, $$\frac1{1+\frac\alpha{n}}=1-\frac\alpha{n}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$$

Comment: Just to elaborate: this is a special case of $(1+x)^\alpha = 1+\alpha x + O(x^2)$ for $x\to 0$, and any fixed $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. Here, take $x=1/n$ and $\alpha=-1$.

Comment: @robjohn But, the definition of Big-O is: O(g(n)) = {f(n) : there exist **positive constants** c and n' such that  0<= f(n) <=c g(n) for all n>=n'.} .But we've a negative constant with the 1/n term. So, it can't engulf the O(1/n^2) term.

Comment: @Mooncrater: No. Straight from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition): One writes $$f(x)=O(g(x))\text{ as }x\to\infty$$ if and only if there is a positive constant $M$ such that for all sufficiently large values of $x$, the $\color{#C00000}{\text{absolute}}$ $\color{#C00000}{\text{value}}$ of $f(x)$ is at most $M$ multiplied by the absolute value of $g(x)$. That is, $f(x)=O(g(x))$ if and only if there exists a positive real number $M$ and a real number $x_0$ such that $$\left|f(x)\right|\le M\left|g(x)\right|\text{ for all }x\ge x_0\text{.}$$

Comment: @robjohn But, that definition is from CLRS, and it clearly emphasizes on positive constants(3rd ed., page 47), it says:$ O(g(n)) $= {$f(n)$ : there exist **positive constants** $c$ and $n_0$ such that $ 0 \leq f(n) \leq cg(n) $ for all $ n \geq n_0$.}

Comment: @Mooncrater: that is not the definition used almost everywhere else. That definition is very limited and not very useful.

Comment: So, the definition in clrs isn't general. Okay. Thanks! @robjohn

Comment: I finally figured out what CLRS is and pulled out my copy (sixth edition). I found essentially what you said on page 26: $$ \scriptsize O(g(n))=\left\{f(n):\text{ there exist positive constants $c$ and $n_0$ such that $0\le f(n)\le c\,g(n)$ for all $n\ge n_0$}\right\}\text{.} $$ The only reason I can see for this restrictive definition is that negative values do not play as big a role when dealing with algorithms, which is the focus of that book. My suggestion is to stick with the definition in Wikipedia when dealing with more general mathematics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the binomial approximation for $(1+y)^k$:

$$
(1+y)^k=1+ky+\Theta(y^2)
$$
as $y \to 0$.

In your case, you can take $k=-1$ to show that any function which is $\frac{1}{1+\Theta(1/n)}$ is also $1+\Theta(\frac{1}{n})$.

Answer (score 5):

We  can  use   Stirling's approximation  formula
\begin{align*}
n!=\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)
\end{align*}
to  prove:

> The  following is valid
>
> \begin{align*}
> C_n=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}= \frac {4^n} { \sqrt {\pi} n^{3/2}} (1+ O(1/n)) \tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> We obtain using (1)
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}&=\frac{1}{n+1}\cdot\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}\\
> &=\frac{1}{n+1}\cdot\sqrt{4\pi n}\left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{2n}\left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\\
> &\qquad
> \cdot \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt {2 \pi n} {\left( \frac {n}{e} \right)}^{n} {\left( 1+ O \left(\frac {1} {n}\right) \right)}}\right)^2\\
> \\
> &=\frac{1}{n+1}\cdot\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\cdot
> \frac{\left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)}{\left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{n\left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)}\cdot\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}
> \left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)^3\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}
> \left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)^4\\
> &=\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi}n^{3/2}}
> \left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\tag{4}\\
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we do some cancellation
- In (3) we use the geometric series expansion
  \begin{align*}
  \frac{1}{1+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}=1+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)
  \end{align*}
- In (4) we use 
  \begin{align*}
  \left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)=1+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)
  \end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/932509), it is shown that
$$
\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi(n+\frac13)}}\le\binom{2n}{n}\le\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi(n+\frac14)}}\tag{1}
$$
Using the fact that as $n\to\infty$,
$$
\begin{align}
(n+a)^b
&=n^b\left(1+\frac an\right)^b\\
&=n^b\left(1+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
we get
$$
\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\left(1+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)\tag{3}
$$
Furthermore
$$
\frac1{n+1}=\frac1n\left(1+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)\tag{4}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi}n^{3/2}}\left(1+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)\tag{5}
$$