# How do I go from Generating function to Asymptotic formula for Catalan Numbers

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics, generating-functions, catalan-numbers

The Catalan Numbers wiki page states that you can prove the asymptotic formula using generating functions, and I was wondering how?

Comment: Catalan Numbers wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Properties This related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1986247/asymptotic-approximation-of-catalan-numbers) is about proving the asymptotic formula using Stirling's approximation (but not generating functions).

Comment: I was looking to show both the Stirling approximation method and the generating function method.

Comment: Where would I find that link on the page?