# Asymptotic behavior of an integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, improper-integrals

Assume that $f(x)\geq 0$ for $0\le x<\infty$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)\, dx<\infty$. Could we conclude that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=0$? My idea is that if we can find a counter example, then $f(x)$ must be an oscillating function in $x$. Any suggestion, idea, or comment is welcome, thanks!

Comment: No, in fact $f$ can be unbounded. Think of  some thin triangles with very small bases and very large heights marching out to infinity.

Comment: Are these thin triangles with the same base and the same height?

Comment: How could they be when the base is small and the height is large?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m\ge0$ and $n\gt2m+2$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty x^m\left(\frac{1+\cos(2\pi x)}2\right)^{x^n}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_0^1(x+k)^m\left(\frac{1+\cos(2\pi(x+k))}2\right)^{(x+k)^n}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\le\sum_{k=0}^\infty(k+1)^m\int_0^1\left(\frac{1+\cos(2\pi x)}2\right)^{k^n}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(k+1)^m\int_0^1\cos^{2k^n}(\pi x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty(k+1)^m\frac1{4^{k^n}}\binom{2k^n}{k^n}\\
&\le1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2^mk^m}{\sqrt{\pi k^n}}\\
&=1+\frac{2^m}{\sqrt\pi}\zeta\left(\frac n2-m\right)
\end{align}
$$
where we've used inequality $(10)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/932509).

Thus, for $m\ge0$ and $n\gt2m+2$,
$$
\int_0^\infty x^m\left(\frac{1+\cos(2\pi x)}2\right)^{x^n}\,\mathrm{d}x\lt\infty
$$
However, for $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, we have $x^m\left(\frac{1+\cos(2\pi x)}2\right)^{x^n}=x^m$, so the function does not tend to $0$.

Here is the plot of this function for $m=1$ and $n=5$:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, you are right there is a counterexample.

Join the following dots: 
$$\left\{\left(n-\frac{1}{2^n},0\right),(n,1),\left(n+\frac{1}{2^n},0\right)\;:\;n\in\mathbb{N}^+\right\}.$$
and you will obtain the graph of a piecewise linear function with the desired property.

P.S. Here is an unbounded version:
$$\left\{\left(n-\frac{1}{4^n},0\right),(n,2^n),\left(n+\frac{1}{4^n},0\right)\;:\;n\in\mathbb{N}^+\right\}. $$

Comment: What do these dots mean?

Comment: @LCH If you join the dots you obtain the graph of a  piecewise linear function with the desired property

Comment: Thanks. For the first case, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}=1$ but, $\lim_{n\to\infty} n\neq 0$, right? I'm curious how come you figure out such an elegant counterexample.

Comment: @LCH Yes, we sum the areas of triangles of base $2/4^n$ and height $2^n$. It is unbounded because $2^n\to+\infty$. You can try to construct your own example.

Comment: You mean "You've voted for this as a useful comment"? I'm a new comer, thanks for the reminding! :)