# Proving inequality $\frac{4^m}{4\sqrt{m}}\le\binom{2m}{m}$ only with Chebyshev inequality

Tags: probability, inequality, binomial-coefficients

What is a good approach to proving this inequality:

> $$\dfrac{4^m}{4\sqrt{m}}\le\binom{2m}{m}$$

using the Chebyshev inequality: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev's_inequality

I thought about using a random variable which has a binomial distribution, but I am not sure.

Thank you!

The answer here: [Elementary central binomial coefficient estimates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58560/elementary-central-binomial-coefficient-estimates)  is **not** good for me, since it doesn't use the Chebychev inequality, I can already do it in an elementary way.

Comment: *Why* do you absolutely to use this inequality for that?

Comment: ive been giving this question as exercise, one exercise is to prove it directly, which i already know how to. the second is to prove it by using chebychev inequality

Comment: You should show your efforts. Instead of "thinking about using a binomial distribution", just use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot **quite** get all the way with just Chebychev, but almost. If any others see a dumb trick I'm missing, please feel free to comment.

Let $X\sim\text{Bin}\left(2m, \displaystyle{1\over 2}\right)$. Then we have that

> $$\begin{cases}
> P(X=n) = \displaystyle{2m\choose n}{1\over 4^m}\le {2m\choose m}{1\over 4^m} \\
> \mu_X = m \\
> \sigma_X = \sqrt{m\over 2}
> \end{cases}$$

So we can use Chebychev with $k=\sqrt{2}$ to get

$$P(|X-m|\ge\sqrt{m})\le {1\over 2}$$
$$\iff P(|X-m|<\sqrt{m})\ge {1\over 2}$$

This means

> $${1\over 2}\le \sum_{n<\sqrt{m}}P(|X-m|=n)<(2\lfloor\sqrt{m}\rfloor+1){2m\choose m}{1\over 4^m}$$
>   $${4^m\over 4\lfloor\sqrt{m}\rfloor + 2}\le {2m\choose m}$$

which is (almost) the desired result. If we break it up a little more, then in the case $m$ is a perfect square our count is for $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\sqrt m-1}P(|X-m|=n)$ giving the **better** bound of

> $${1\over 2}\le (2\sqrt{m}-1){2m\choose m}{1\over 4^m}.$$