# Prove that $\frac1{2^i}\sum\limits_{j=0}^i|2j-i| \binom{i}{j} \leq d\sqrt{i}$ for some constant $d$

Tags: inequality, summation, binomial-distribution

> I'm trying to give a bound on the following formula:
>   $$\frac1{2^i}\sum_{j=0}^i|2j-i| \binom{i}{j} \leq d\sqrt{i}$$ for some constant $d$.

This is how far I get:
$$=\dfrac{\sum^{i/2}_{j=0} \ \binom{i}{j} (i - 2j) + \sum^{i}_{j=(i/2)+1} \ \binom{i}{j} (2j - i)}{2^i}$$
$$\leq  \dfrac{2\sum^{i/2}_{j=0} \ \binom{i}{j} (i - 2j)}{2^i}$$
If I take the sum from j=0 to i instead of i/2, then the sum would be 0. So, I should use another way of upper bounding this formula.

Comment: The LHS is $E(|X_1+\cdots+X_i|)$ where $(X_k)$ is i.i.d. uniform on $\{-1,+1\}$. By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, this is less than the square root of $E((X_1+\cdots+X_i)^2)=E(X_1^2)+\cdots+E(X_i^2)=i$.

Comment: @Did Thank you! How did you figure out that this is probability! I did not mention that! you're really smart guy! it is amazing short answer! Best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to go on with your approach.
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^i|2j-i| \binom{i}{j} 
&=2\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor i/2\rfloor}(i-2j) \binom{i}{j}\\
&=2i\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor i/2\rfloor}\binom{i}{j}-4\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor i/2\rfloor}j\binom{i}{j}\\
&=2i\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor i/2\rfloor}\binom{i}{j}-4i\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor i/2\rfloor}\binom{i-1}{j-1}\\
&=2i\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor i/2\rfloor}\binom{i}{j}-4i\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor i/2\rfloor-1}\binom{i-1}{j}\\
&=2i\binom{i}{\lfloor i/2\rfloor}+2i\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor i/2\rfloor-1}\underbrace{\left(\binom{i-1}{j-1}-\binom{i-1}{j}\right)}_{\leq 0}\\
&\leq 2i\binom{i}{\lfloor i/2\rfloor}.
\end{align}
Now show that the inequality holds for $d=2$ (I am aware that the one-line proof in Did's comment show that $d=1$ suffices).

It remains to show that for $i\geq 1$,
$$2i\binom{i}{\lfloor i/2\rfloor}\leq 2 \cdot 2^i\sqrt{i}\quad\text{or}\quad \binom{i}{\lfloor i/2\rfloor}\leq \frac{2^i}{\sqrt{i}}.$$

P.S. Take a look here: [Elementary central binomial coefficient estimates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58560/elementary-central-binomial-coefficient-estimates?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: But $d=1$ works like a charm, see the one-line proof in my comment.

Comment: @Did Yes, I read it. Very cool! Why don't you write an answer with a few more details? P.S. I edited my answer.