# Does $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} {2m\choose m} \frac{1}{4^{m}} $ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I would like to check if the series $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}  {2m\choose m} \frac{1}{4^{m}} $ converges or diverges. The ratio test is inconclusive. Any other way to proceed? Thanks.

Comment: As an aside, note: $$(1-4x)^{-1/2} = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \binom{2m}{m} x^m$$

Comment: In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/932509), it is shown, using [Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality), that $$\frac1{\sqrt{\pi\!\left(n+\frac13\right)}}\le\frac1{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\le\frac1{\sqrt{\pi\!\left(n+\frac14\right)}}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Striling's approximation to see that $\binom {2m} {m}4^{-m} \geq c m^{-1/2}$ for some $c>0$. Hence the series is divergent.

Comment: Reference for Striling's approximation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: Thanks @Kavi Rama Murthy

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}
&=\frac{2n(2n-1)}{4n^2}\frac1{4^{n-1}}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}\\
&=\frac{n-\frac12}{n}\frac1{4^{n-1}}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}\\
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
\frac1{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{k-\frac12}{k}
$$
and therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\left[\frac1{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\right]^2
&=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{k^2-k+\frac14}{k^2}\\
&\ge\frac14\prod_{k=2}^n\frac{k-1}{k}\\
&=\frac1{4n}
\end{align}
$$
So we see that for $n\ge1$,
$$
\frac1{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\ge\frac1{2\sqrt{n}}
$$
so the sum diverges.

Comment: Quite surprising how you squeezed the square root out of the expression to get a much better bound than my one. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an elementary ''non-Stirling'' approach:

\begin{eqnarray*} \frac{1}{4^m}\binom{2m}{m}
& = & \frac{1}{4^m}\cdot \frac{\prod_{i=1}^m 2i \cdot \prod_{i=1}^m (2i-1) }{(m!)^2} \\
& = & \frac{1}{4^m}\cdot 4^m\frac{\prod_{i=1}^m i \cdot \prod_{i=1}^m \left(i-\frac{1}{2}\right) }{\prod_{i=1}^m i \cdot \prod_{i=1}^m i} \\
& = & \prod_{i=1}^m \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2i} \right)\\
& = & \prod^m_{i=\color{blue}{1}} \frac{2i-1}{2i} \\
& \color{blue}{>} & \frac{1}{2} \prod^m_{i=\color{blue}{2}} \frac{2i-2}{2i} \\
& = & \frac{1}{2} \prod_{i=2}^m \frac{i-1}{i} \\
& = & \frac{1}{2m} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Hence, the given series has the **divergent minorant** $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2m}$.

Comment: Note that with a similar, non-Stirling approach, we can get the stronger bound $\frac1{2\sqrt{n}}$.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Sterling approximation, $$n! \approx \sqrt {2\pi n}(n/e)^n$$

Therefore      $$ {2m\choose m} \approx \frac {4^m}{\sqrt {2\pi m}}$$

Which makes the series $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}  {2m\choose m} \frac{1}{4^{m}}$diverge.

Comment: Actually, $\binom{2m}{m}\sim\frac{4^m}{\sqrt{\pi m}}\left(1-\frac1{8m}+\dots\right)$

Answer (score 0):

Considering the partial sums
$$S_p=\sum_{m=0}^{p} {2m\choose m} \frac{1}{4^{m}}=\binom{p+\frac{1}{2}}{p}$$ and using Stirling approximation, we have
$$\log(S_p)=\log \left(\frac{2 \sqrt{p}}{\sqrt{\pi }}\right)+\frac{3}{8 p}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^2}\right)$$ Then, continuing with Taylor series
$$S_p=e^{\log(S_p)}=\frac{2 \sqrt{p}}{\sqrt{\pi }}+\frac{3}{4 \sqrt{p\pi }} +O\left(\frac{1}{p^{3/2}}\right)$$ For $S_{10}$, the exact value is $\frac{969969}{262144}\approx 3.70014$ while the truncated series gives $\frac{83}{4 \sqrt{10 \pi }}\approx 3.70206$.

For $p > 23$, the relative error is $< 0.01$%.

Answer (score 0):

The mere divergence of $\displaystyle\sum_{m=0}^\infty \binom{2m}m \frac1{4^m}$ follows from the easy bound
$$
4^m = \sum_{k=0}^{2m} \binom{2m}k \le \sum_{k=0}^{2m} \binom{2m}m = (2m+1)\binom{2m}m,
$$
so that $\displaystyle\sum_{m=0}^\infty \binom{2m}m \frac1{4^m} \ge \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac1{2m+1}$.