# Reference for an upper bound of central binomial coefficient

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients

The wikipedia page of [central binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient) mentions an upper bound of the central binomial coefficient $$\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}(1-\frac{c_n}{n}),\quad c_n\in (1/9,1/8),\forall n\ge 1\,.$$
However I was unable to find any reference or proof of this inequality. It would be great if anyone would show me a reference for it so that I can learn the techniques. Thank you.

Comment: There is a very good paper at https://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/043_00_JIPAM/043_00.pdf

Comment: Have a look at @robjohn's answer in this question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58560/elementary-central-binomial-coefficient-estimates

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici thank you for the great references!

Comment: You are very welcome ! The second one I sent is very nice (simple when you know the answer !) as all work done by @robjohn, a very eminent user in this site. Cheers.