# Binomial coefficients summation

Tags: summation, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

I have the following expression,

$$
\frac{1}{n 4^n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} i \binom{2n}{n + i},
$$

and I'm wondering if one can get either an exact formula for the sum involving binomial coefficient or get a tight asymptotic bound for the whole expression.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This expression is [hypergeometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) and thus there are algorithmic methods for computing closed form. You can see wolframalpha compute a closed form for you [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+%2F+%28n+*+4%5En%29+*+sum%28j+*+binom%282*n%2C+n%2Bj%29%2C+j%2C+1%2C+n%29)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have worked on a similar expression:

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^{n}{2j\cdot\binom{2n}{n+j}}&=\sum_{j=1}^{n}{(n+j)\cdot\binom{2n}{n+j}}-\sum_{j=1}^{n}{(n-j)\cdot\binom{2n}{n+j}}\\
\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n}{(n+j)\cdot\binom{2n}{n+j}}-\sum_{j=1}^{n}{(n-j)\cdot\binom{2n}{n-j}}
\end{align}
$$

Imagine choosing several of $2n$ people to be in a committee and then electing one of the committee as a leader. The first term on right hand side is the number of possibilities where the committees consist of at least $n+1$ members while the other term is where the committees consist of at most $n-1$ members.

We can select the leader first and then complete the committees. If there are at least $n+1$ members of committee, then there are at most $n-1$ non committee. If there are at most $n-1$ members, then there are at most $n-2$ members aside from the leader.

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^{n}{2j\cdot\binom{2n}{n+j}}&=2n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\binom{2n-1}{k}}-2n\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}{\binom{2n-1}{k}}\\
\\
&=2n\cdot\binom{2n-1}{n-1}
\end{align}
$$

From this result we can get solution to your problem:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n\cdot 4^{n}}\sum_{j=1}^{n}{j\cdot\binom{2n}{n+j}}&=\frac{1}{2n\cdot 4^{n}}\sum_{j=1}^{n}{2j\cdot\binom{2n}{n+j}}\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{2n\cdot 4^{n}}\cdot 2n\cdot\binom{2n-1}{n-1}\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{4^{n}}\cdot\binom{2n-1}{n-1}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Note that you can simply it further to $$\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}\binom{2n}{n}.$$

Comment: @Gary Oh right that is true

Answer (score 1):

If you want approximations or bounds, use the result given by Wolfram Alpha.
$$S_n=\frac{1}{n\, 4^n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} i \binom{2n}{n + i}=\frac{4^{-n} n \Gamma (2 n)}{\Gamma (n+1)^2}$$ Take logarithms and use Stirling approximation to obtain
$$\log\left(S_n\right)=-\frac{1}{2} \log (4 \pi  n)-\frac{1}{8 n}+\frac{1}{192 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$ Continue with Taylor using
$$S_n=e^{\log\left(S_n\right)}=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi n} }\Bigg[1-\frac{1}{8 n}+\frac{1}{128 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\Bigg]$$

Comment: Related:  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/59247