# Show that $\binom{2n}{n} = \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}} \left(1+\mathcal{O}\bigl(\frac{1}{n}\bigr)\right)$

Tags: asymptotics, binomial-coefficients, limsup-and-liminf

> Show that $\binom{2n}{n} = \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}} \left(1+\mathcal{O}\bigl(\frac{1}{n}\bigr)\right)$.
>
> Hint: It might be useful that for $f,g: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ with $f(n) = \mathcal{O}(g(n))$ and $g(n) = \mathcal{o}(1)$ holds $\frac{1}{1+f(n)} = 1 +\mathcal{O}(g(n))$.

I tried to evaluate the limit superior of

$$ \bigg\lvert \frac{\binom{2n}{n} - \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}} }{\frac{1}{n}} \bigg\rvert = \bigg\lvert \frac{2n \cdots (n+1)}{(n-1)!} - \frac{4^n\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \bigg\rvert$$

, but I do not get farther than that. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: I don't think I know a way to do this one without Stirling.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Elementary central binomial coefficient estimates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58560/elementary-central-binomial-coefficient-estimates)

Comment: I think as written that error can't be right? I think you want $(1 + \mathcal{O}(1/n))$?

Comment: Yeah, seems unlikely to be true, but maybe, as prets suggests: $$\binom{2n}n=\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\left(1+\mathcal O\left(\frac 1n\right)\right)$$

Comment: Basically, the reason this seems unlikely to be true is that we use Stirling's formula to prove this, using $$n!=\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac ne\right)^n\left(1+\mathcal O\left(\frac 1n\right)\right)$$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo and corrected it

Comment: But now your limit superior method would never get the right result. Now you need the limit superior of $$n\left|\left(\binom{2n}{n}\frac{\sqrt{\pi n}}{4^n}-1\right)\right|$$

Comment: If you don't already know Stirling's approximation, the weird part is the $\sqrt{\pi n},$ which might seem to jump out of nowhere.

Comment: But the hint would seem to imply using Stirling. Then you get: $$\binom{2n}n=\frac{\sqrt{4\pi n}\left(\frac {2n}e\right)^{2n}\left(1+O\left(\frac1{2n}\right)\right)}{2\pi n\left(\frac ne\right)^{2n}\left(1+O\left(\frac 1n\right)\right)^2}=\dfrac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\dfrac{\left(1+O\left(\frac1{2n}\right)\right)}{\left(1+O\left(\frac 1n\right)\right)^2}$$ The hint seems to be to help you resolve that right part - how to show: $$\dfrac{\left(1+O\left(\frac1{2n}\right)\right)}{\left(1+O\left(\frac 1n\right)\right)^2}=1+O\left(\frac 1n\right)$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I understand that $\mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{2n}) = \mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{n})$, but I am not sure if we can use cancellation law for fractions containing big Ohs.

Comment: @3nondatur You can't just cancel, since you could have $(1+1/n)/(1+2/n)$ for example. But there is still something you can do instead to show the relation Thomas Andrews wrote...

Comment: @Ian: Sorry, but I do not get it.

Comment: Hint: Firs show $(1+O(1/n))^2=1+O(1/n).$ Then show: $$\frac{1+O(1/n)}{1+o(1/n)}=1+O(1/n)$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Thanks a lot, I get it now.