# Trying to show that $\binom{2m}{m} \leq 2^{2m} \frac{2m-1}{6m}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, upper-lower-bounds

I am trying to show the folllowing property:

$\binom{2m}{m} \leq 2^{2m} \frac{2m-1}{6m} \ \  \ \ \ $  (for $m\geq 4$)

I first tried using the known result: $\binom{n}{k} \leq (\frac{ne}{k})^k$ however it doesn't seem to work. I'm stuck at this point.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58560/elementary-central-binomial-coefficient-estimates and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133732/upper-limit-on-the-central-binomial-coefficient

Comment: @lhf - thanks!  :)

Comment: You should not expect $\binom nk \le \frac{n^k}{k!} \le (\frac{ne}{k})^k$ to work well when $k$ is linear in $n$. Even when $k$ is around $\sqrt n$ it might not always be good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be proved by induction.

If $m=4$, then $\binom{2m}{m}=70$ and $2^{2m}\frac{2m-1}{6m}=\frac{224}{3}$. And $70=\frac{210}3<\frac{224}{3}$.

Now, take $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and assume that
$$
\binom{2m}m\le2^{2m}\frac{2m-1}{6m}.\label{ineq}\tag1
$$Then, since
$$
\binom{2(m+1)}{m+1}=\binom{2m}m\times\frac{4m+2}{m+1}
$$
and
$$2^{2(m+1)}\frac{2(m+1)-1}{6(m+1)}=2^{2m}\frac{2m-1}{6m}\times\frac{4m(2m+1)}{(m+1)(2m-1)}
$$
then, in order to deduce from \eqref{ineq} that
$$
\binom{2(m+1)}{m+1}\le2^{2(m+1)}\frac{2(m+1)-1}{6(m+1)},
$$
it is enough to prove that
$$
\frac{4m+2}{m+1}\le\frac{4m(2m+1)}{(m+1)(2m-1)}.
$$
But we have
\begin{align}
\frac{4m+2}{m+1}\le\frac{4m(2m+1)}{(m+1)(2m-1)}&\iff2(2m+1)\le\frac{4m(2m+1)}{2m-1}\\
&\iff2\le\frac{4m}{2m-1}\\
&\iff4m-2\le4m,
\end{align}
and this is a true statement.