# Asymptotic formula for ratio of double factorials

Tags: calculus, limits, factorial

I am interested in getting an asymptotic formula for
$$
\frac{(2n-1)!!} {(2n)!!}.
$$

After some trial and error, I think the asymptotic can be of the form $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha n + \beta}}.$

Use Stirling's formula, I got $\alpha = \pi$

Using software, I was able to get $\beta = \frac{\pi}{4}$, but I have no idea how to prove this.

So my question is: how do I show that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\left(\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!}\right)^{2} - \pi n\right) = \frac{\pi}{4}
$$
?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you take an extra term in [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Speed_of_convergence_and_error_estimates), you have

- $n! = \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n \left(1 +\frac{1}{12n} + O(\frac1{n^2})\right)$
- $(2n)! =\sqrt{4\pi n}\left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{2n} \left(1 +\frac{1}{24n} + O(\frac1{n^2})\right)$
- $(2n)!! = 2^n n! = \sqrt{2n\pi}\left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{n} \left(1 +\frac{1}{12n} + O(\frac1{n^2})\right)$
- $(2n-1)!! = \frac{(2n)!}{(2n)!!} = \sqrt{2}\left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{n} \left(1 -\frac{1}{24n} + O(\frac1{n^2})\right)$
- $\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!} = \sqrt{n\pi}\left(1 +\frac{1}{8n} + O(\frac1{n^2})\right)$
- $\left(\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!} \right)^2= {n\pi}\left(1 +\frac{1}{4n} + O(\frac1{n^2})\right) = n\pi+\frac\pi4+ O(\frac1{n})$

which seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 9):

$$A_n=\frac{(2n-1)!!} {(2n)!!}=\frac{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } \,\,\Gamma (n+1)}$$ Take logarithms, use twice Stirling approximation and then Taylor series
$$\log(A_n)=-\frac{1}{2} (\log (n)+\log (\pi ))-\frac{1}{8 n}+\frac{1}{192
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$ Continuing wtit Taylor
$$A_n=e^{\log(A_n)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n\pi }} \left(1-\frac{1}{8 n}+\frac{1}{128 n^2}+\frac{5}{1024  n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right) \right)$$
$$\frac 1{A_n^2}-\pi n=\frac \pi 4\left(1+\frac{1}{8 n}-\frac{1}{32
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right) \right)$$ which is in a relative error of $0.01$% when $n>4$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
\begin{align*}
\frac{{(2n - 1)!!}}{{(2n)!!}} & = \frac{{\Gamma \!\left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)}}{{\sqrt \pi  \Gamma (n + 1)}} = \frac{1}{\pi }\int_0^1 {t^{n - 1/2} (1 - t)^{ - 1/2} {\rm d}t} \\ & = \frac{1}{\pi }\int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - (n + 1/2)s} (1 - {\rm e}^{ - s} )^{ - 1/2} {\rm d}s} \\ &
 = \frac{1}{\pi }\int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - (n + 1/4)s} s^{ - 1/2} \sqrt {\frac{{s/2}}{{\sinh (s/2)}}} {\rm d}s} 
\end{align*}
for $n\ge 0$. Now
$$
s^{ - 1/2} \sqrt {\frac{{s/2}}{{\sinh (s/2)}}}  = s^{ - 1/2}  - \frac{{s^{3/2} }}{{48}} + \frac{{s^{7/2} }}{{2560}} -  \ldots 
$$
as $s\to 0^+$. Thus, by [Watson's lemma](https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.3#ii),
$$
\frac{{(2n - 1)!!}}{{(2n)!!}} \sim \frac{1}{{\sqrt {\pi (n + 1/4)} }}\left( {1 - \frac{1}{{64(n + 1/4)^2 }} + \frac{3}{{4096(n + 1/4)^4 }} -  \ldots } \right)
$$
as $n\to+\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Inequality $(9)$ in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/932509) says that
$$
\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi\!\left(n+\frac14+\frac1{16n+12}\right)}}\le\binom{2n}{n}\le\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi\!\left(n+\frac14\right)}}\tag1
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\color{#C00}{(2n)!!}}{\color{#090}{(2n-1)!!}}
&=\frac{\color{#C00}{2^nn!}\color{#090}{2^nn!}}{\color{#090}{(2n)!}}\tag{2a}\\[3pt]
&=\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}\tag{2b}\\
&\in\left[\sqrt{\pi\!\left(n+\tfrac14\right)},\sqrt{\pi\!\left(n+\tfrac14+\tfrac1{16n+12}\right)}\right]\tag{2c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a):}$ rewrite double factorials in terms of factorials
$\text{(2b):}$ $\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}$
$\text{(2c):}$ apply $(1)$

Squaring $(2)$ and subtracting $\pi n$ gives
$$
\frac\pi4\le\left(\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!}\right)^2-\pi n\le\frac\pi4+\frac\pi{16n+12}\tag3
$$
Evaluate the limit with the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

[image]

Comment: (+1) I found this relation to the central binomial coefficient too (seemed important, (2b) above). I was using its known asymptotic expansion to show the result and then saw your answer!