# Approximating a sum of products of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, numerical-methods, binomial-coefficients

I have a function I want to approximate the growth of in a closed form:

$$\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n} |n-i-j|\binom{n+i-j}{i}\binom{n-i+j-1}{j}}{\binom{2n}{n}}$$

Without the absolute value term, this sort of resembles Vandermonde's identity, but I'm a bit stuck trying to resolve the function with this term. I've also tried expressing it as a polynomial

$$\left(\frac{1}{2\pi i}\right)^2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n}|n-k-j|\oint_{|z|\ =\ 1}{\left(1 + z\right)^{n+k-j} \over z^{k+1}}dz\oint_{|z|\ =\ 1}{\left(1 + z\right)^{n+j-k-1} \over z^{n-k}}dz $$

which seems to lead no where. Can anyone suggest a way forward?

Comment: Your numerator seems to be $4^{n-1}n.$ (but I do not have proof.)

Comment: Then using $\binom{2n}{n} \approx 4^n / \sqrt{\pi n}$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/58646/28545)) gives an approximation $\frac{\sqrt{\pi} }{4}n^{3/2}$ for your expression. This is accurate to about $.1\%$ for $n = 100$.

Comment: I computed the sum and found the sequence in [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A002697). (If I were more observant I could have just noticed the pattern.)

Comment: @Quantum If you just accepted my answer then you should consider adding your work to the post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We seek a closed form of

$$\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} \sum_{q=0}^n 
|n-p-q| {n+p-q\choose p} {n-p+q-1\choose q}.$$

#### First part

We get for the argument to the absolute value being positive the
contribution

$$\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} \sum_{q=0}^{n-1-p} 
(n-p-q) {n+p-q\choose p} {n-p+q-1\choose q}.$$

This is

$$\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} \sum_{q=0}^{n-1-p} 
(q+1) {n+p-(n-1-p-q)\choose p} 
{n-p+(n-1-p-q)-1\choose n-1-p-q}
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^{n-1} \sum_{q=0}^{n-1-p} 
(q+1) {2p+q+1\choose p} 
{2n-2p-q-2\choose n-p-q-1}
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^{n-1} \sum_{q=0}^p
(q+1) {2(n-1-p)+q+1\choose n-1-p} 
{2n-2(n-1-p)-q-2\choose n-(n-1-p)-q-1}
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^{n-1} \sum_{q=0}^p
(q+1) {2n-2p+q-1\choose n-1-p} 
{2p-q\choose p-q}
\\ = [z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{2n-1} 
\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} z^p (1+z)^{-2p}
\sum_{q=0}^p
(q+1) (1+z)^q
{2p-q\choose p-q}
\\ = [z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{2n-1} 
\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} z^p (1+z)^{-2p} [w^p] (1+w)^{2p}
\\ \times \sum_{q=0}^p
(q+1) (1+z)^q w^q (1+w)^{-q}.$$

We may extend the inner sum to infinity due to the coefficient
extractor in $w$, getting

$$[z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{2n-1} 
\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} z^p (1+z)^{-2p} [w^p] (1+w)^{2p}
\frac{1}{(1-(1+z)w/(1+w))^2}
\\ = [z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{2n-1} 
\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} z^p (1+z)^{-2p} [w^p] (1+w)^{2p+2}
\frac{1}{(1+w-(1+z)w)^2}
\\ = [z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{2n-1} 
\sum_{p\ge 0} z^p (1+z)^{-2p} [w^p] (1+w)^{2p+2}
\frac{1}{(1-wz)^2}.$$

Here we have extended to infinity due to the extractor in $z.$
The contribution from $w$ is

$$\;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{w^{p+1}} (1+w)^{2p+2} \frac{1}{(1-wz)^2}.$$

Now put $w/(1+w)=v$ so that $w=v/(1-v)$ and $dw = 1/(1-v)^2 \; dv$ to
get

$$\;\underset{v}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{v^{p+1}} \frac{1}{(1-v)^{p+1}}
\frac{1}{(1-vz/(1-v))^2} \frac{1}{(1-v)^2}
\\ = \;\underset{v}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{v^{p+1}} \frac{1}{(1-v)^{p+1}}
\frac{1}{(1-v-vz)^2}.$$

Next put $v = (1-\sqrt{1-4u})/2$ so that $v(1-v)=u$ and $dv = 
1/\sqrt{1-4u} \; du$ to obtain

$$\;\underset{u}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{u^{p+1}}
\frac{1}{(1-(1+z)(1-\sqrt{1-4u})/2)^2}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4u}}.$$

Evaluate at $u=z/(1+z)^2$ to cancel the remaining sum (substitution
rule), here we get

$$\sqrt{1-4u} = \sqrt{1-4z/(1+z)^2}
= \frac{1}{1+z} \sqrt{(1+z)^2-4z}
= \frac{1-z}{1+z}$$

and obtain

$$[z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{2n-1}
\frac{1}{(1-(1+z)(1-(1-z)/(1+z))/2)^2}
\frac{1+z}{1-z}
\\ = [z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{2n-1}
\frac{1}{(1-(1+z-(1-z))/2)^2}
\frac{1+z}{1-z}
\\ = [z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{2n}
\frac{1}{(1-z)^3}.$$

#### Second part

We get for the argument to the absolute value being negative the
contribution

$$- \sum_{p=0}^{n-1} \sum_{q=n-p}^n 
(n-p-q) {n+p-q\choose p} {n-p+q-1\choose q}
\\ = - \sum_{p=0}^{n-1} \sum_{q=0}^p 
(n-p-(n-q)) {n+p-(n-q)\choose p} {n-p+n-q-1\choose n-q}
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^{n-1} \sum_{q=0}^p 
(p-q) {p+q\choose p} {2n-p-q-1\choose n-q}
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^{n-1} \sum_{q=0}^p 
q {2p-q\choose p} {2n-2p+q-1\choose n-p+q}
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^{n-1} \sum_{q=0}^p 
q {2p-q\choose p-q} {2n-2p+q-1\choose n-1-p}.$$

We  have the  first part  with $q$  replaced by  $q+1$ and
adjust the infinite series accordingly, getting:

$$[z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{2n-1} 
\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} z^p (1+z)^{-2p} [w^p] (1+w)^{2p}
\frac{(1+z)w/(1+w)}{(1-(1+z)w/(1+w))^2}
\\ = [z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{2n} 
\sum_{p\ge 0} z^p (1+z)^{-2p} [w^{p-1}] (1+w)^{2p+1}
\frac{1}{(1-wz)^2}.$$

We extended $p$  to infinity due to the  extractor in $z.$
Unfortunately this isn't  quite a repeat so we  need to do
the residues one more time. We have

$$\;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{w^{p}} (1+w)^{2p+1} \frac{1}{(1-wz)^2}.$$

Now again put $w/(1+w)=v$ so that $w=v/(1-v)$ and $dw = 1/(1-v)^2 \; dv$
to  get

$$\;\underset{v}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{v^{p}} \frac{1}{(1-v)^{p+1}}
\frac{1}{(1-vz/(1-v))^2} \frac{1}{(1-v)^2}
\\ = \;\underset{v}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{v^{p}} \frac{1}{(1-v)^{p}}
\frac{1}{(1-v-vz)^2} \frac{1}{1-v}.$$

Next put $v = (1-\sqrt{1-4u})/2$ so that $v(1-v)=u$ and $dv = 
1/\sqrt{1-4u} \; du$ to obtain

$$\;\underset{u}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{u^{p}}
\frac{1}{(1-(1+z)(1-\sqrt{1-4u})/2)^2}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4u}}
\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4u}}{2u}.$$

Evaluate at $u=z/(1+z)^2$ to cancel the remaining sum (substitution
rule, same as before),

$$[z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{2n}
\frac{1}{(1-(1+z)(1-(1-z)/(1+z))/2)^2}
\frac{1+z}{1-z} \frac{1-(1-z)/(1+z)}{2}
\\ = [z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{2n}
\frac{1}{(1-(1+z-(1-z))/2)^2}
\frac{z}{1-z}
\\ = [z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{2n}
\frac{z}{(1-z)^3}
= [z^{n-2}] (1+z)^{2n}
\frac{1}{(1-z)^3}.$$

#### Conclusion

It remains to add up the two pieces. We have

$$[z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{2n}
\frac{1}{(1-z)^3}
+ [z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{2n}
\frac{z}{(1-z)^3}
\\ = [z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{2n+1} \frac{1}{(1-z)^3}.$$

This is

$$S = \;\underset{z}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{z^n} (1+z)^{2n+1} \frac{1}{(1-z)^3}.$$

Residues sum to zero so we may evaluate using minus the residues at
$z=1$ and at infinity. We require for the former (flip sign one more
time)

$$\frac{1}{2} 
\left.\left[ \frac{1}{z^n} (1+z)^{2n+1} \right]''\right|_{z=1}
\\ = \frac{1}{2} 
\left.\left[ - \frac{n}{z^{n+1}} (1+z)^{2n+1} 
+ \frac{1}{z^{n}} (2n+1) (1+z)^{2n} \right]'\right|_{z=1}
\\ = \frac{1}{2}
\left[ n(n+1) 2^{2n+1} - n(2n+1) 2^{2n}
- n (2n+1) 2^{2n} + (2n+1)(2n) 2^{2n-1} \right]
\\ = \frac{1}{2} n 4^n.$$

We get from the residue at infinity with the sign flipped

$$\;\underset{z}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{z^2}
z^n (1+1/z)^{2n+1} \frac{1}{(1-1/z)^3}
\\ = \;\underset{z}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{z^2}
z^n (1+z)^{2n+1} \frac{1}{z^{2n+1}} \frac{z^3}{(z-1)^3}
= - \;\underset{z}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{z^n}
(1+z)^{2n+1} \frac{1}{(1-z)^3} = - S.$$

We have shown that $S= \frac{1}{2} n 4^n - S$ or alternatively

$$S= n 4^{n-1}.$$

#### Asymptotics

OP   asks   to  scale   $S$   by   the  central   binomial
coefficient. This will produce

$${2n\choose n}^{-1} n 4^{n-1}
\sim \frac{\sqrt{\pi n}}{4^n} n 4^{n-1}
= \frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\pi} n^{3/2}.$$

#### Acknowledgement

I would like to dedicate  this computation to G. Egorychev
who sadly is no longer with us as of December 2023.

Comment: Great work! Interesting and instructive contribution. (+1)