Non Induction proof of $\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n} n!^2} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+1}}$
IIT JEE (1987) asked for the Induction proof of $$P=\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n} n!^2} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+1}}~~~~~~(*)$$
which is commonly available.
Upon simplification, we get
$$P=\frac{1}{2}.
   \frac{3}{4}.  \frac{5}{6} 
\frac{7}{8}\dots \frac{2n-1}{2n}.$$
In an  attempt to produce a non-induction proof, I use $\frac{a}{b}< \frac{a+x}{b+x}$, if $0<a<b$ and $x > 0.$
So, $P<Q$, if $$Q=\frac{2}{3}.\frac{4}{5}.\frac{6}{7}. \dots \frac{2n}{2n+1}.$$
$$ P^2 \le PQ=\frac{1}{2n+1}.$$
$$\implies P< \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}},$$
which is a weaker result than $(*)$.
The question is: What could be a non induction proof of $(*)$?

I suppose you mean $\frac{1}{2n+1}$ in the penultimate line.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58560/elementary-central-binomial-coefficient-estimates/932509#932509 may be useful.

You have written $PQ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$, which I am fairly sure is not correct.

@J.S. Oh! Yes I corrected it now.

We can prove a stronger version of the previous lemma, which is:
$$
P \leq Q \times \frac{2n+1}{3n+1}.
$$
I will use the inequality $\frac{Q'}{P} \geq 1$ for the proof, where $Q' = Q \times \frac{2n+1}{3n+1}$.
We have:
$$
\frac{Q'}{P} = \frac{4}{3} \times \frac{16}{15} \times \frac{36}{35} \times \dots \times \frac{4n^2}{4n^2-1} \times \frac{2n+1}{3n+1} = f(n),
$$
where
$$
f(n) = \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{4k^2}{4k^2-1} \times \frac{2n+1}{3n+1}.
$$
Note that $f(0) = 1$. If we can prove that $f(n)$ is an increasing function in $n$, then the result follows. To do so, we will use the technique $\frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)} \geq 1$.
Now,
$$
\frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)} = \frac{4(n+1)^2}{4(n+1)^2-1} \times \frac{(2n+3)(3n+1)}{(3n+4)(2n+1)} \geq 1.
$$
Expanding the inequality, we get:
$$
(4n^2 + 8n + 4)(6n^2 + 11n + 3) \geq (4n^2 + 8n + 3)(6n^2 + 11n + 4),
$$
which simplifies to:
$$
2n^2 + 3n \geq 0.
$$
This inequality holds for all $n \geq 0$.
Thus, we have shown that:
$$
P^2 \leq P \times Q \times \frac{2n+1}{3n+1} \Rightarrow P^2 \leq \frac{1}{3n+1} \Rightarrow P \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+1}}.
$$
Apologies for the somewhat messy proof.
